# Draw the Devil's Staircase

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

The [Devil's Staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a fractal-like function related to the Cantor set.

[image]

Your task is to replicate this funky function — in ASCII art!

## Input

A single integer `n >= 0`, indicating the size of the output. Input may be given via STDIN, function argument or command-line argument.

## Output

The ASCII-art rendition of the Devil's staircase at size `n`, either returned as a string or printed to STDOUT. Trailing spaces at the end of each row are okay, but leading spaces are not. You may optionally print a single trailing newline.

For size `0`, the output is just:

```
x
```

(If you wish, you may use any other printable ASCII character other than space, in place of `x`.)

For size `n > 0`, we:

- Take the output of size `n-1` and stretch each row by a factor of three
- Riffle between rows of single `x`s
- Shift the rows rightward so that there is exactly one `x` in each column, and the position of the first `x` are minimal while decreasing with the rows

For example, the output for `n = 1` is:

```
    x
 xxx
x
```

To get the output for `n = 2`, we stretch each row by a factor of three:

```
            xxx
   xxxxxxxxx
xxx
```

Riffle between rows of single `x`'s:

```
x
            xxx
x
   xxxxxxxxx
x
xxx
x
```

Shift rightward:

```
                  x
               xxx
              x
     xxxxxxxxx
    x
 xxx
x
```

As another example, [here](http://pastebin.com/LWcwJVHA) is `n = 3`.

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the solution in the fewest bytes wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pyth, 30

```
jb_u+G+*leGd*HNu+N+^3hTNUQ]1]k
```

This is a program that takes input from STDIN and uses grc's method of finding the Cantor set. Uses the " character to display the curve.

[Try it online here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Explanation:

I will explain the code in two parts, first, the cantor set generation:

```
u+N+^3hTNUQ]1
u        UQ]1         : reduce( ... , over range(input), starting with [1])
 +N                   : lambda N,T: N + ...
   +^3hTN             : 3 ** (T+1) + N   (int + list in pyth is interpreted as [int] + list)
```

And the output formatting:

```
jb_u+G+*leGd*HN    ]k
jb_                    : "\n".join(reversed(...)
   u               ]k  : reduce(lambda G,H: ... , over cantor set, starting with [""])
    +G+*leGd           : G + len(G[-1]) * " " + ...
            *HN        : H * '"'
```

Note that in pyth N = '"' by default.

Answer (score 36):

### J (<s>73</s> <s>68</s> <s>58</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>35</s> 34 characters)

After thinking about the problem for some time, I found an entirely different way to generate the Devil's Staircase pattern. The old answer including its explanation has been removed, you can look into the revisions of this answer to figure out how it was.

This answer returns an array of blanks and sharps, representing the devil's staircase.

```
' #'{~1(]|.@=@#~[:,3^q:)2}.@i.@^>:
```

Here is the answer split into its two parts in explicit notation:

```
f =: 3 : '|. = (, 3 ^ 1 q: y) # y'
g =: 3 : '(f }. i. 2 ^ >: y) { '' #'''
```

### Explanation

The approach is a bit different, so observe and be amazed.

1. `>: 3` – three incremented, that is,

   ```
   4
   ```
2. `2 ^ >: 3` – two to the power of three incremented, that is,

   ```
   16
   ```
3. `i. 2 ^ >: 3` – the first `2 ^ >: 3` integers, that is,

   ```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
   ```
4. `}. i. 2 ^ 4` – the first `2 ^ >: 3` integers, beheaded, that is,

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
   ```

   Let's call this sequence `s`; we enter `f` now.
5. `1 q: s` – the exponents of 2 in the prime decomposition of each item of `s`. In general, `x q: y` yields a table of the exponents for the first `x` primes in the prime decomposition of `y`. This yields:

   ```
   0
   1
   0
   2
   0
   1
   0
   3
   0
   1
   0
   2
   0
   1
   0
   ```
6. `3 ^ 1 q: s` – three to the power of these exponents, that is,

   ```
    1
    3
    1
    9
    1
    3
    1
   27
    1
    3
    1
    9
    1
    3
    1
   ```
7. `, 3 ^ 1 q: s` – the ravel (that is, the argument with it's structure collapsed into a vector) of the previous result. This is needed because `q:` introduces an unwanted trailing axis. This yields

   ```
    1 3 1 9 1 3 1 27 1 3 1 9 1 3 1
   ```
8. `(, 3 ^ 1 q: s) # s` – each item of `s` replicated as often as the corresponding item in the previous result, that is,

   ```
   1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 10 10 10 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 14 14 14 15
   ```
9. `= (, 3 ^ 1 q: s) # s` – the self classification of the previous result, this is, a matrix where each row represents one of the unique items of the argument, each column represents the corresponding item of the argument and each cell represents whether the items of row and column are equal, that is,

   ```
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   ```
10. `|. = (, 3 ^ 1 q: s) # s` – the previous result flipped along the vertical axis.
11. `(|. = (, 3 ^ 1 q: s) # s) { ' #'` – the items of the previous result used as indices into the array `' #'`, so `0` is replaced by   and `1` is replaced by `#`, that is,

    ```
                                                                    #
                                                                 ### 
                                                                #    
                                                       #########     
                                                      #              
                                                   ###               
                                                  #                  
                       ###########################                   
                      #                                              
                   ###                                               
                  #                                                  
         #########                                                   
        #                                                            
     ###                                                             
    #
    ```

    the result we want.

Comment: Inside the power loop `(,],~3^#@~.)@]` instead of `(1,[:,1,"0~3*])`  saves 1 byte. And if you're ok with `!` as output char `u:32+` instead of `' #'{~` saves another one.

Comment: `#\ ` instead of `i.@#` and you overtake APL! :)

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work because a cap would be needed, but I found another way to beat APL.

Comment: The new output is the staircase for the `n-1` not for `n`.

Comment: @randomra Ah… that's shitty. Let me see if it's fixable.

Comment: @randomra Not fixable. Let's see if beating APL is possible by other means.

Comment: Very interesting approach. You can extract the factors of 2 from a number `m` with `m&-m` (C or Ruby syntax). See my answer http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/46861/15599 I dont' know if it will be useful in any way.

Comment: @steveverrill That's a bit tricky to get right. Let me check…

Comment: @randomra Now we are on par with APL.

Comment: 30 bytes: `' x'{~[:|.@=@I.3&(1,~1,@,.*)&1` -- retains the excellent self-classify idea, but uses a different method to generate the step sizes -- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7PC4IwFMDxu3/Fo4Hbar6auw2KURAE0aGrKURo2aHoBySY/us2zYuQHXZ48Pm@t3M1QJrAVAMFARPQ9nkIi@16WVHIaF4G@o1malaoXCZFKYUROOSurLizmSMov047MJQua6Fyh1zqBnYQI2THf7s4Sx/P9HKE/eXxiu/1dmJDycKmJHaFUNFNc79Ak6KJZt8u0Kw@QcrR2BQocuS7np9YaY32cqS1/y89YzFvKYAdGO8pnPhwukICfvUB "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 30):

## [Hexagony](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony), 217 bytes

This was immensely fun. Thank you for posting this challenge.

Full disclosure: The language (Hexagony) did not exist at the time this challenge was posted. However, I did not invent it, and the language was not designed for this challenge (or any other specific challenge).

```
){_2"_{\"{{""}"{'2//_.\><*\"\/_><[\]/3\'\_;|#__/(\2\'3_'}(#:|{$#{>_\//(#={/;01*&"\\_|[##={|}$_#></)]$_##|){*_.>.(/?#//~-="{}<_"=#/\}.>"%<.{#{x\"<#_/=&{./1#_#>__<_'\/"#|@_|/{=/'|\"".{/>}]#]>(_<\'{\&#|>=&{{(\=/\{*'"]<$_
```

Laid out hexagonally:

```
        ) { _ 2 " _ { \ "
       { { " " } " { ' 2 /
      / _ . \ > < * \ " \ /
     _ > < [ \ ] / 3 \ ' \ _
    ; | # _ _ / ( \ 2 \ ' 3 _
   ' } ( # : | { $ # { > _ \ /
  / ( # = { / ; 0 1 * & " \ \ _
 | [ # # = { | } $ _ # > < / ) ]
$ _ # # | ) { * _ . > . ( / ? # /
 / ~ - = " { } < _ " = # / \ } .
  > " % < . { # { x \ " < # _ /
   = & { . / 1 # _ # > _ _ < _
    ' \ / " # | @ _ | / { = /
     ' | \ " " . { / > } ] #
      ] > ( _ < \ ' { \ & #
       | > = & { { ( \ = /
        \ { * ' " ] < $ _
```

The program does not actually use the `#` instruction, so I used that character to show which cells are genuinely unused.

How does this program work? That depends. Do you want the short version, or the long?

## Short explanation

To illustrate what I mean by “line” and “segment” in the following explanation, consider this dissection of the intended output:

```
segments →
 │   │ │         │ │   │x   lines
─┼───┼─┼─────────┼─┼───┼─     ↓
 │   │ │         │ │xxx│
─┼───┼─┼─────────┼─┼───┘
 │   │ │         │x│
─┼───┼─┼─────────┼─┘
 │   │ │xxxxxxxxx│
─┼───┼─┼─────────┘
 │   │x│
─┼───┼─┘
 │xxx│
─┼───┘
x│
```

With that explained, the program corresponds to the following pseudocode:

```
n = get integer from stdin

# Calculate the number of lines we need to output.
line = pow(2, n+1)

while line > 0:
    line = line - 1

    # For all segments except the last, the character to use is spaces.
    ch = ' ' (space, ASCII 32)

    # The number of segments in each line is
    # equal to the line number, counting down.
    seg = line

    while seg > 0:
        seg = seg - 1

        # For the last segment, use x’s.
        if seg = 0:
            ch = 'x' (ASCII 120)

        # Calculate the actual segment number, where the leftmost is 1
        n = line - seg

        # Output the segment
        i = pow(3, number of times n can be divided by 2)
        i times: output ch

    output '\n' (newline, ASCII 10)

end program
```

## Long explanation

Please refer to this color-coded code path diagram.

[image: Execution path]

Execution starts in the top left corner. The sequence of instructions `){2'"''3''"2}?)` is executed (plus a few redundant cancelations, like `"{` etc.) by pursuing a fairly convoluted path. We start with Instruction Pointer #0, highlighted in crimson. Halfway through, we switch to #1, starting in the top-right corner and painted in forest green. When IP #2 starts out in cornflower blue (middle right), the memory layout is this:

[image: Memory layout]

Throughout the entire program, the edges labeled **2a** and **2b** will always have the value `2` (we use them to calculate 2ⁿ⁺¹ and to divide by 2, respectively) and the edge labeled **3** will always be `3` (we use that to calculate 3ⁱ).

We get to business as we enter our first loop, highlighted in cornflower blue. This loop executes the instructions `(}*{=&}{=` to calculate the value 2ⁿ⁺¹. When the loop exits, the saddle brown path is taken, which takes us to Instruction Pointer #3. This IP merely dabbles along the bottom edge westwards in goldenrod yellow and soon passes control to IP #4.

The fuchsia path indicates how IP #4, starting in the bottom left, proceeds swiftly to decrement **line**, set **ch** to `32` (the space character) and **seg** to (the new value of) **line**. It is due to the early decrement that we actually start with 2ⁿ⁺¹−1 and eventually experience a last iteration with the value 0. We then enter the first *nested* loop.

We turn our attention to the branching indigo, where, after a brief decrement of **seg**, we see **ch** updated to `x` only if **seg** is now zero. Afterwards, **n** is set to **line − seg** to determine the actual number of the segment we’re in. Immediately we enter another loop, this time in the fair color of tomato.

Here, we figure out how many times **n** (the current segment number) can be divided by 2. For as long as the modulo gives us zero, we increment **i** and divide **n** by 2. When we are satisfied **n** is no longer thusly divisible, we branch into the slate gray, which contains two loops: first it raises 3 to the power of the **i** we calculated, and then it outputs **ch** that many times. Observe that the first of these loops contains a `[` instruction, which switches control to IP #3 — the one that was only taking baby steps along the bottom edge earlier. The body of the loop (multiplying by 3 and decrementing) is executed by a lonely IP #3, imprisoned in an endless dark olive green cycle along the bottom edge of the code. Similarly, the second of these slate gray loops contains a `]` instruction, which activates IP #5 to output **ch** and decrement, shown here in dark Indian red. In both cases, those Instruction Pointers trapped in servitude obediently execute one iteration at a time and yield control back to IP #4, only to bide the moment for their service to be called upon once again. The slate gray, meanwhile, rejoins its fuchsia and indigo brethren.

As **seg** inevitably reaches zero, the indigo loop exits into the lawn green path, which merely outputs the newline character and promptly merges back into the fuchsia to continue the **line** loop. Beyond the final iteration of the **line** loop lies the short sable ebon path of ultimate program termination.

Comment: Now this is just plain old-fashioned insanity.

Answer (score 23):

## Python 2, 78 bytes

```py
L=[1]
i=3
exec"L+=[i]+L;i*=3;"*input()
while L:x=L.pop();print' '*sum(L)+'x'*x
```

Starting off with the list `L=[1]`, we duplicate it and insert the next power of 3 in the middle, resulting in `[1, 3, 1]`. This is repeated `n` times to give us the row lengths for the Devil's staircase. Then we print each row padded with spaces.

Answer (score 20):

## APL, 38

```
⊖↑'x'/⍨¨D,⍨¨0,¯1↓-+\D←{1,⍨∊1,⍪3×⍵}⍣⎕,1
```

Example:

```
      ⊖↑'x'/⍨¨D,⍨¨0,¯1↓-+\D←{1,⍨∊1,⍪3×⍵}⍣⎕,1
⎕:
      2
                  x
               xxx 
              x    
     xxxxxxxxx     
    x              
 xxx               
x
```

Explanation:

```
⊖↑'x'/⍨¨D,⍨¨0,¯1↓-+\D←{1,⍨∊1,⍪3×⍵}⍣⎕,1

                                     ⎕       ⍝ read a number from the keyboard
                       {           }⍣ ,1      ⍝ apply this function N times to [1]
                               3×⍵           ⍝ multiply each value by 3
                           ∊1,⍪               ⍝ add an 1 in front of each value
                        1,⍨                  ⍝ add an 1 to the end
                     D←                      ⍝ store values in D (lengths of rows)
                   +\                        ⍝ get running sum of D
                  -                          ⍝ negate (negative values on / give spaces)
             0,¯1↓                           ⍝ remove last item and add a 0 to the beginning
                                             ⍝ (each row needs offset of total length of preceding rows)   
         D,⍨¨                                ⍝ join each offset with each row length
   'x'/⍨¨                                    ⍝ get the right number of x-es and spaces for each row
 ↑                                           ⍝ make a matrix out of the rows
⊖                                            ⍝ mirror horizontally
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: I love that the explanation of the code looks like a Devil's Staircase.

Comment: I found an even shorter APL solution.

Answer (score 14):

## GNU sed, 142

Not the shortest answer, but its sed!:

```
s/$/:/
:l
s/x/xxx/g
s/:/:x:/g
tb
:b
s/^1//
tl
s/:x/X/g
s/^/:/
:m
s/.*:([Xx]+)Xx*:$/&\1:/
tm
:n
s/([ :])[Xx](x*Xx*)/\1 \2/g
tn
s/:/\n/g
s/X/x/g
```

Because this is sed (no native arithmetic), I'm taking liberties with the rule *"A single integer n >= 0, indicating the size of the output"*.  In this case the input integer must be a string of `1`s, whose length is n.  I think this is *"indicating"* the size of the output, even though it is not a direct numerical equivalent to n.  Thus for n=2, the input string will be `11`:

```
$ echo 11 | sed -rf devils-staircase.sed

                  x
               xxx
              x
     xxxxxxxxx
    x
 xxx
x

$
```

This appears to complete with exponential time complexity of O(c<sup>n</sup>), where c is about 17. n=8 took about 45 minutes for me.

---

Alternatively if it is required that n is entered numerically exactly, then we can do this:

#### sed, 274 bytes

```
s/[0-9]/<&/g
s/9/8Z/g
s/8/7Z/g
s/7/6Z/g
s/6/5Z/g
s/5/4Z/g
s/4/3Z/g
s/3/2Z/g
s/2/1Z/g
s/1/Z/g
s/0//g
:t
s/Z</<ZZZZZZZZZZ/g
tt
s/<//g
s/$/:/
:l
s/x/xxx/g
s/:/:x:/g
tb
:b
s/^Z//
tl
s/:x/X/g
s/^/:/
:m
s/.*:([Xx]+)Xx*:$/&\1:/
tm
:n
s/([ :])[Xx](x*Xx*)/\1 \2/g
tn
s/:/\n/g
s/X/x/g
```

#### Output:

```
$ echo 2 | sed -rf devils-staircase.sed

                  x
               xxx
              x
     xxxxxxxxx
    x
 xxx
x

$
```

Comment: This is really cool.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 81

```
def f(n,i=1,s=0):
 if i<2<<n:q=3**len(bin(i&-i))/27;f(n,i+1,s+q);print' '*s+'x'*q
```

**Program version (88)**

```
def f(n,s=0):
 if n:q=3**len(bin(n&-n))/27;f(n-1,s+q);print' '*s+'x'*q
f((2<<input())-1)
```

The number of x's in the `n`th 1-indexed row is 3 to the power of (the index of the first set bit in `n`, starting from the lsb).

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 74

```python
def f(n,s=0):
 if~n:B=3**n;A=s+B-2**n;f(n-1,A+B);print' '*A+'x'*B;f(n-1,s)
```

A recursive approach. The size-$n$ devil's staircase is split into three parts

- The left recursive branch, a staircase of size `n-1`, whose length is `3**n - 2**n`
- The center line of `x`', of length `3**n`
- The right recursive branch, a staircase of size `n-1`, whose length is `3**n - 2**n`

Note that the total length of the three parts is `3*(3**n) - 2*(2**n)` or `3**(n+1) - 2**(n+1)`, which confirms the induction.

The optional variable `s` stores the offset of the current parts we're printing. We first recurse down to the left branch with larger offset, then print the center line, then do the right branch at the current offset.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33 bytes

Here is another CJam approach (I haven't looked at Optimizer's code, so I don't know if it's actually much different):

```
L0sl~{{3*0s}%0s\+}*{1$,S*\+}%W%N*
```

This uses `0` for the curve. Alternatively, (using grc's trick)

```
LLl~){3\#a1$++}/{1$,S*\'x*+}%W%N*
```

which uses `x`.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=L0sl~%7B%7B3*0s%7D%250s%5C%2B%7D*%7B1%24%2CS*%5C%2B%7D%25W%25N*&input=3)

### Explanation

The basic idea is to first form an array with the rows, like

```
["0" "000" "0" "000000000" "0" "000" "0"]
```

And then to go through this list, prepending the right amount of spaces.

```
L0sl~{{3*0s}%0s\+}*{1$,S*\+}%W%N*
L                                 "Push an empty string for later.";
 0s                               "Push the array containing '0. This is the base case.";
   l~                             "Read and evaluate input.";
     {           }*               "Repeat the block that many times.";
      {    }%                     "Map this block onto the array.";
       3*                         "Triple the current string.";
         0s                       "Push a new zero string.";
             0s\+                 "Prepend another zero string.";
                   {       }%     "Map this block onto the result.";
                    1$            "Copy the last line.";
                      ,S*         "Get its length and make a string with that many spaces.";
                         \+       "Prepend the spaces to the current row.";
                             W%   "Reverse the rows.";
                               N* "Join them with newlines.";
```

The other version works similarly, but creates an array of lengths, like

```
[1 3 1 9 1 3 1]
```

And then turns that into strings of `x`s in the final map.

Answer (score 6):

### Dyalog APL, 34 characters

Using the approach by grc. Draws the staircase with `⌹` (domino) characters and takes input from stdin. This solution assumes `⎕IO←0`.

```
' ⌹'[(∪∘.=⊖){⍵/⍳≢⍵}⊃(⊢,,)/3*⌽⍳1+⎕]
```

- `⎕` – take input from stdin.
- `⌽⍳1+⎕` – the sequence of the numbers from `⎕` down to 0. (e.g. `3 2 1 0`)
- `3*⌽⍳1+⎕` – three to the power of that (e.g. `27 9 3 1`)
- `(⊢,,)/3*⌽⍳1+⎕` – the previous result folded from the right by the tacit function `⊢,,` which is equal to the dfn `{⍵,⍺,⍵}` yielding the step lengths of the devil's staircase as per grc's approach.
- `{⍵/⍳≢⍵}⊃(⊢,,)/3*⌽⍳1+⎕` the step lengths converted into steps.
- `(∪∘.=⊖){⍵/⍳≢⍵}⊃(⊢,,)/3*⌽⍳1+⎕` that self-classified, as in my [J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/46821/draw-the-devils-staircase/46826#46826). Notice that `⊖` already flips the result correctly.
- `' ⌹'[(∪∘.=⊖){⍵/⍳≢⍵}⊃(⊢,,)/3*⌽⍳1+⎕]` the numbers replaced by blanks and dominoes.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 99

A different answer to my other one, inspired by FUZxxl's answer

FUZxxl notes that the numbers of x's correspond to the number of factors of 2 of the index. for example for n=2 we have the following factorization:

```
1 =1
2 =1 * 2
3 =3
4 =1 * 2 * 2
5 =5
6 =3 * 2
7 =7
```

I use a rather more straightforward way of extracting these powers of 2: `i=m&-m` which yields the sequence `1 2 1 4 1 2 1` etc. This works as follows:

`m-1` is the same as `m`in its most significant bits, but the least significant 1's bit becomes a zero, and all the zeros to the right become 1's.

To be able to AND this with the original, we need to flip the bits. There are various ways of doing this. One way is to subtract it from `-1`.

The overall formula is then `m& (-1 -(m-1))`  which simplifies to `m&(-m)`

Example:

```
          100   01100100
100-1=     99   01100011
-1-99=   -100   10011100
100&-100=   4   00000100
```

Here's the code: newlines are counted, indents are unnecessary and therefore not counted, as my other answer. It's slightly longer than my other answer due to the clumsy conversion from base 2: `1 2 1 4 1 2 1 etc` to base 3: `1 3 1 9 1 3 1 etc` (is there a way to avoid that `Math::` ?)

```
def s(n)
  a=[]
  t=0
  1.upto(2*2**n-1){|m|i=3**Math::log(m&-m,2)
    a.unshift" "*t+"x"*i 
    t+=i}
  puts a
end
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 99 characters

```
d=q.((iterate((1:).(>>=(:[1]).(*3)))[1])!!)
q[]=[];q(a:r)=sum r&' '++a&'x'++'\n':q r
(&)=replicate
```

The function is `d`:

```
λ: putStr $ d 3
                                                                x
                                                             xxx
                                                            x
                                                   xxxxxxxxx
                                                  x
                                               xxx
                                              x
                   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                  x
               xxx
              x
     xxxxxxxxx
    x
 xxx
x
```

Comment: All these parentheses! Is there really no way to get around with less?

Comment: You can lose a byte by swapping the equations for `q` and doing `q x=x` in the empty list case. Also, it seems that the parentheses around `iterate...[1]` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 137 bytes

```php
function f($n){for($a=[];$i<=$n;array_push($a,3**$i++,...$a))$r=str_repeat;foreach($a as$v){$o=$r(' ',$s).$r(x,$v)."
$o";$s+=$v;}echo$o;}
```

I'm using here the same trick as [grc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/46824/11713). Here is the ungolfed version:

```php
function staircase($n)
{
    $lengthsList = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; ++$i) {
        array_push($lengthsList, 3 ** $i, ...$lengthsList);
    }

    $output = '';
    $cumulatedLength = 0;
    foreach ($lengthsList as $length)
    {
        $output = str_repeat(' ', $cumulatedLength) . str_repeat('x', $length) . "\n" . $output;
        $cumulatedLength += $length;
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: `3**$i` --> feels like PHP 5.6. You should specify it. This is incompatible with almost every installation of PHP. To save you a few bytes, you should start with `$r=str_repeat;` and where you have that function, you can replace with `$r`, saving you 2 bytes. Also, `$r('x',$v)` can be `$r(x,$v)` and it will work fine (notice that I've already replaced the function name with the variable). Also, I believe that `++$i<=$n` can be rewritten as `$n>++$i` saving you another byte.

Comment: Here is your function, with a little cool trick: `function f($n){$r=str_repeat;$a=[1];while($n>++$i)$a=array_merge($a,[3**$i],$a);foreach($a as$v){$o=$r(' ',$s).$r(x,$v)."\r$o";$s+=$v;}echo$o;}` (instead of having that ugly newline, I've added the escape sequence `\r` inside a double-quoted string, with the variable `$o` inside it. Thus `"\r$o"` has the same byte-count as the `''.$o` one, with newline ommited on the last one and produces the same result.

Comment: Actually, the condition of the `while` has to be `$n>$i++` for this reduction to work properly.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel PHP 5.6 is the last version of PHP, I don't have to say anything more. It's not my fault if almost everybody is using an old version, and if the majority is using an obsolete one. Thanks for the `$r=str_repeat` trick. I've been thinking only about `$r='str_repeat';`, which was not saving any byte. The undefined constant is a good trick also, well done ;). A newline is one byte smaller than writing `\n`, so I've kept it, but I've used double quotes to avoid a concatenation with `$0`. Thanks again !

Comment: It would only look good on you. If I wasn't aware of the `3 ** $i` I would say that you have a terrible syntax. You may address that correction. I'm saying about this one only and not the `[1]` because that came from PHP5.4, which is quite 'old'. 1 year ago, I would ask you to specify that. Today, I ask you to simply specify (in a very short line) that specifies this. Speaking about the code, you still have the `++$i<=$n` which can be replaced with `$n>$i++`. I had to convert all your code into PHP5.3 to test it. Which was painful. But I see you ate 7 bytes so far.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `++$i<$n` isn't possible anymore with the new code reduction I've just done. Always uglier, always shorter :).

Comment: Well, at least it's shorter, right?

Comment: Late adoption of PHP releases is generally recommended. I wouldn't even recommend using 5.5 at this point. The current "stable" release is now on revision 22, and the last two revisions alone fixed over 50 bugs.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>140</s> 99

My second ever Ruby code, and my first nontrivial use of the language. Suggestions are most welcome. Byte count excludes leading spaces for indents, but includes newlines (it seems most of the newlines cannot be deleted unless they are replaced by a space at least.)

Input is by function call. Output is an array of strings, which ruby conveniently dumps to stdout as a newline-separated list with a single `puts`.

The algorithm is simply `new iteration` = `previous iteration` +  `extra row  of n**3 x's` + `previous iteration`. However there is <s>a lot</s> *a fair amount* of code just to get the leading spaces in the output right.

```
def s(n)
  a=["x"]
  1.upto(n){|m|t=" "*a[0].length
    a=a.map{|i|t+" "*3**m+i}+[t+"x"*3**m]+a}
  puts a
end
```

## Edit: Ruby, 97

This uses the similar but different approach of building a numeric table of all the numbers of x's required in array `a` in the manner described above, but then building a table of strings afterwards. The table of strings is built backwards in array `c` using the rather oddly named `unshift` method to prepend to the existing array.

Currently this approach is looking better - but only by 2 bytes :-)

```
def s(n)
  a=c=[]
  (n+1).times{|m|a=a+[3**m]+a}
  t=0
  a.each{|i|c.unshift" "*t+"x"*i
    t+=i}
  puts c
end
```

Comment: You can replace `for m in(0..n-1)do ... end` with `n.times{|m|...}`.

Comment: @Omar Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow. You wouldn't believe how much effort it took to get that to run, due to the constant syntax errors. I didn't know how to access the iterating variable for `n.times` and I will certainly remember that. It eliminates an `end` too! However on this occasion I was wondering if `for m in (1..n)` might be better, to avoid the `(m+1)`. Is there a shorter way of writing that?

Comment: `for` is long mainly because you are forced to use `end` (you can replace the `do` with a newline or with `;`). For `1..n` you can use `1.upto(n){|m|...}`. I like the look of `(1..n).each{|i|...}` but it is slightly longer than using `upto`. And note that iterating by calling `each` or `upto` isn't just shorter, it's also consider more idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: @Thanks again, `1.upto(n)` it is! With that and a few unnecessary brackets gone, I'm already down to 120. I think below 100 is possible, I will post the revised code later.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 165

```
#define W while
f(n){int i=n+1,j=1<<i,k=1,l,r,s,t;W(i--)k*=3;l=k-j;W(--j){r=j,s=1;W(!(r%2))r/=2,s*=3;l-=s;t=l;W(t--)putchar(32);W(++t<s)putchar(88);putchar('\n');}}
```

Here's the same code unpacked and slightly cleaned up:

```
int f(int n) {
    int i=n+1, j=1<<i, k=1;
    while (i--) k*=3;
    int l=k-j;
    while (--j) {
        int r=j,s=1;
        while (!(r%2))
            r/=2, s*=3;
        l-=s;
        int t=l;
        while (t--) putchar(' ');
        while (++t<s) putchar('X');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

This is based on the same idea as FUZxxl's solution to the problem, of using an explicit rather than implicit form for the rows.  The declaration of j sets it to 2^(n+1), and the first while loop computes k=3^(n+1); then l=3^(n+1)-2^(n+1) is the total width of the staircase (this isn't too difficult to prove).  We then go through all the numbers r from 1 to 2^(n+1)-1; for each one, if it's divisible by (exactly) 2^n then we plan on printing s=3^n 'X's.  l is adjusted to make sure we start from the right spot: we write l spaces and s 'X's, then a newline.

Comment: define W to ;while and omit int to save some characters.

Comment: also t=l-=s for some saving.

Comment: @FUZxxl I tried both of those, but while C still allows implicit types on functions it wasn't allowing them on variable declarations even with the 'classic' flags (at least on GCC).  And I tried #define W ;while and it didn't seem to care for it, though I may have slipped up in the definition.

Comment: hm... I think you can only omit the type in a global variable. It doesn't bring you very much. You can try to add `(*p)()=putchar;` at the beginning to call `putchar` as `p`. I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>46 43 41 39 36</s> 35 bytes

```
L0ri),(a*+_W%(;+{3\#'x*+_,S*}%$1>N*
```

*UPDATE* using a different approach now.

---

Old approach:

```
]ri){3f*_,)"x"a*\]z:+}*_s,f{1$,U+:U-S*\N}
```

Pretty naive and long, but something to get started.

Will add explanation once I golf it.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=L0ri)%2C(a*%2B_W%25(%3B%2B%7B3%5C%23'x*%2B_%2CS*%7D%25%241%3EN*&input=2)

Comment: Seems to need some work. Did not work properly for n =4, 5, 17.  Displayed  left-formatted riffles strings of x's at the upper part. With n=17 it dumped code to the screen and filled the bottom with x's.

Comment: @DavidCarraher For 4, 5 I think that's just the line wrapping. If you copy the output to a text editor with no line wrapping it looks okay to me.

Comment: Ok.  I know see.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>271</s> 269 bytes

Uses grc's method.

```java
import java.util.*;String a(int a){List<Integer>b=new ArrayList<>();int c=-1,d=1;for(;c++<a;b.add(d),b.addAll(b),b.remove(b.size()-1),d*=3);String f="";for(;b.size()>0;f+="\n"){d=b.remove(b.size()-1);for(int g:b)for(c=0;c<g;c++)f+=' ';for(c=0;c<d;c++)f+='x';}return f;}
```

Indented:

```java
import java.util.*;
String a(int a){
    List<Integer>b=new ArrayList<>();
    int c=-1,d=1;
    for(;c++<a;b.add(d),b.addAll(b),b.remove(b.size()-1),d*=3);
    String f="";
    for(;b.size()>0;f+="\n"){
        d=b.remove(b.size()-1);
        for(int g:b)
            for(c=0;c<g;c++)
                f+=' ';
        for(c=0;c<d;c++)
            f+='x';
    }
    return f;
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

2 bytes thanks to mbomb007

Comment: You could use `b.size()>0` instead of `!b.isEmpty()`, saving 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 16 bytes

```
Eɽ2Ǒ3$e₌ÞR‡\x*꘍Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiRcm9MseRMyRl4oKMw55S4oChXFx4KuqYjeG5mCIsIiIsIjIiXQ==)

```
Eɽ               # range(1, 2**n-1)
  2Ǒ             # Multiplicity when divided by 2
    3$e          # 3 ** n
       ₌         # Apply both of the following to that:
        ÞR       # Cumulative sums with tail removed and 0 prepended
          ‡\x*   # And that many asterisks
              ꘍Ṙ # Pad with spaces to (cumulative sums) and reverse
```

Comment: your outputs are offset by one (`0` should output `x`)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 104 <s>106 118</s>

**Edit** Removed the recursive function, the list of '*' for each line is obtained iteratively, fiddling with bits and powers of 3 (like in many other answers)
Inside the loop, a multiline string is buuilt from bottom up, keeping a running count of leading spaces to add on each line

```js
F=n=>{
  for(i=a=s='';++i<2<<n;a=s+'*'.repeat(t)+'\n'+a,s+=' '.repeat(t))
    for(t=u=1;~i&u;u*=2)t*=3;
  return a
}
```

**First Try** removed

The recursive R function build an array with the number of '*' for each line.
For instance R(2) is `[1, 3, 1, 9, 1, 3, 1]`
This array is scanned to build a multiline string from bottom up, keeping a running count of leading spaces to add on each line

```js
F=n=>
(R=n=>[1].concat(...n?R(n-1).map(n=>[n*3,1]):[]))(n)
.map(n=>a=' '.repeat(s,s-=-n)+'*'.repeat(n)+'\n'+a,a=s='')
&&a
```

**Test** In Firefox/FireBug console

```
F(3)
```

*Output*

```
                                                                *
                                                             ***
                                                            *
                                                   *********
                                                  *
                                               ***
                                              *
                   ***************************
                  *
               ***
              *
     *********
    *
 ***
*
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 62

```
#!perl -p
eval's/x+/$&$&$&
x/g,s/\d*/x
/;'x++$_;s/x+/$"x$'=~y!x!!.$&/ge
```

First calculates the result iteratively without the leading spaces. Then adds them before each line according to the number of `x` characters in the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

### R - 111 characters

Straightforward implementation, building up the array iteratively and destroying it slowly.

```
n=scan()
a=1
if(n)for(x in 1:n)a=c(a,3^x,a)
for(A in a){cat(rep(' ',sum(a)-A),rep('x',A),'\n',sep='');a=a[-1]}
```

Usage:

```
> source('devil.r')
1: 2
2: 
Read 1 item
                  x
               xxx
              x
     xxxxxxxxx
    x
 xxx
x
```

Comment: Good point, modified my code so it takes the `n` argument from the command line

Comment: You save 8 bytes by reading from STDIN. `n=scan()`.

Comment: You don't need to declare `x` to use it as a cursor, nor do you need `if(n)`. Also, line breaks count as a character I think.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about `x`. Not sure about `if(n)` however. I added that part to deal with the case `n=0`. The `if(n)` then returns `F` and hence returns a single `x`. If I remove it, `n=0` gives unwanted results. New here, so didn't know about line breaks. Included now!

Comment: If you set `a=0` and start the loop at `x in 0:n` it also works for n=0. Then you can omit the `if(n)`.

Comment: If I'm right, that produces zeros between the steps (0 1 0 3 0 1 0), and consequently empty lines between the steps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 41 bytes

```
!→⁰¡(↔§z+ömR' h∫mLtΘ`:"x"ṁȯe"x"Ṙ3f≠' );"x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/FR26RHjRsOLdR41Dbl0PIq7cPbcoPUFTIedazO9Sk5NyPBSqlC6eHOxhPrU8GMGcZpjzoXqCtoWitV/P//3xgA)

Creates an infinite list of graphs and indexes into them, cause why not.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 64 bytes

```julia
!n=n<1 ? "x" : [' '^(L=2*3^n-2^n).*(m=!(n-1));lpad('x'^3^n,L);m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCsIwEEDRfU8x6SYzxYqpXbUNXqA3EAOBKIykY6gV4ulj8e8e//mJ7E0uRYmVycAF6lzDAFcN2uFsu@bspO2c0LHBxSqU1hCNMfmAOmu338NM43Irj9cKDCxwGvoK9gK/U/RfVEx/p5Vli4JU3SWUHw)

output is a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 81 bytes

```hs
d=unlines.f
f 0=["x"]
f n|z<-f$n-1=z%[[1..3^n]>>"x"]%z
a%b=map((a!!0>>" ")++)b++a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclNCoMwEEDhvacYgwElJChuGy/RZbAw/qSVxiE0ChI8e1O7e3zvheE9O5fSpHdyC81B2cxCrQ07WH8VnfEmbUGy0ZEb0yjVPqjvuv/mMUM@6BV9WWKe15cCq4SoBiEwrbgQaPD7dt8@UMAEbfqO1uEzJDl6/wM)

I counted `d=` to compete fairly with the older answer here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
‘2*Ṗọ2 3*µạ+ɼ;¹⁾ xx)ṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//4oCYMirhuZbhu40yIDMqwrXhuqErybw7wrnigb4geHgp4bmaWf///zM)

```
‘2*Ṗọ2 3*µạ+ɼ;¹⁾ xx)ṚY Main monadic link
‘                      Increment
 2*                    2 to the power
   Ṗ                   Range from 1 exclusive
    ọ2                 Order of 2
       3*              3 to the power
         µ         )   Map:
          ạ              Absolute difference with
           +ɼ              increment the register by the number
             ;           Join with
              ¹            the number
               ⁾ xx      Repeat " x" that many times
                    Ṛ  Reverse
                     Y Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0$F3*€1Ć}©×®ηO0š¨úR»
```

Outputs with `0` as character instead of `x` (could be any other digit by replacing the leading `0`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//zAkRjMq4oKsMcSGfcKpw5fCrs63TzDFocKow7pSwrv//zI) or [verify the first few test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W98bJKSZ15BaYmVgpK9nw6Xkn9pCYSn898gws/NWOtR0xrDI221h1Yenn5o3bnt/gZHFx5acXhX0KHd/3UObbP/DwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
0            # Push a 0
 $           # Push a 1 and the input-integer
  F          # Pop the input, and loop that many times:
   3*        #  Multiply the values by 3
     €1      #  Push a 1 before each integer in the list
       Ć     #  Enclose to also have a trailing 1
  }©         # After the loop: store the result in variable `®` (without popping)
    ×        # Pop it, and repeat the initial 0 that many times as string(s)
   ®         # Push list `®` again
    η        # Pop and push its prefixes
     O       # Sum each inner prefix
      0š     # Prepend a leading 0
        ¨    # Remove the last item
         ú   # Pad the "x"-string with that many leading spaces
          R  # Reverse the list
           » # Join the lines by newlines
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```