# Compute the Digit Difference Sum of a Number

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, sequence

Consider taking some non-negative integer such as 8675309 and computing the absolute values of the differences between all the pairs of neighboring digits.

For \$8675309\$ we get \$|8-6| = 2\$, \$|6-7| = 1\$, \$|7-5| = 2\$, \$|5-3| = 2\$, \$|3-0| = 3\$, \$|0-9| = 9\$. Stringing these results together yields another, smaller non-negative integer: \$212239\$. Repeating the process gives \$11016\$, then \$0115\$, which by the convention that leading zeros are not written simplifies as \$115\$, which becomes \$04\$ or \$4\$, which can't be reduced any further. Summing all these values up we get \$8675309 + 212239 + 11016 + 115 + 4 = 8898683\$.

Let's define the Digit Difference Sum (or DDS) as this operation of repeatedly taking the digit differences of a number to form a new number, then adding all the resulting numbers to the original.

Here are the first 20 values in the corresponding DDS sequence:

```
N   DDS(N)
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  11
11  11
12  13
13  15
14  17
15  19
16  21
17  23
18  25
19  27
```

[Here are the first 10000 values](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=smY5B93g), the graph for which is quite curious:

[image: DDS 10000 plot]

Especially since it looks the same when you plot it to 1000 or even 100:

[image: DDS 1000 plot]

[image: DDS 100 plot]

(I'd call it the dentist's [staircase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46821/26997)...)

## Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in a non-negative integer and prints or returns its DDS value. For example, if the input was `8675309`, the output should be `8898683`.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: dentist's staircase?

Comment: @MartijnR Dentist's staircase.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Orthodontist's staircase?

Comment: @BetaDecay **Dentist**'s staircase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth, 17

```
s.ui.aM-VJjNTtJTQ
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.ui.aM-VJjNTtJTQ&input=8675309&debug=0) or run the [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.ui.aM-VJjNTtJTQ&input=19&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A8675309&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
s.u            Q   # Cumulative reduce, i.e. getting the intermediate values of each reduce
                     step and returning them as a list, then sum the list
   i ... T         # Convert the resulting list of numbers into a base 10 number
   .aM             # Get the absolute value of each element of ...
      -VJjNTtJ     # Perform vector subtraction on the lists given by
        JjNT       # assign J the number we currently have converted to its base 10 digits
            tJ     # and J[1:]. e.x. for 123 we get J = [1,2,3] then we do
                   # zip(J,J[1:]) which gives [[1,2],[2,3]] then element wise subtract
                   # to get [-1, -1]
```

Comment: What language is this? So cryptic! T_T

Comment: @asgs Welcome to PPCG :) It's called Pyth, you can find an interpreter and some documentation at its [Github page](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth). Most of the users of this language are active on this site, so if you have questions about it feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or the [room dedicated to it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24159/pyth) :)

Answer (score 17):

## Python 2, 73

Luckily, I managed to avoid any string operations.

```
t=lambda n:n>9and abs(n%10-n/10%10)+10*t(n/10)
g=lambda n:n and n+g(t(n))
```

`g` is the function that computes the answer.

Comment: What is this black magic?!

Comment: @BetaDecay I believe it's called "math".

Comment: I don't know Python quite well enough to tell, but can you apply the remainder operation to both terms in one hit? That is, would `(n-n/10)%10` operate the same as `n%10-n/10%10`? Or maybe even `(9*n/10)%10`?

Comment: @GlenO In Python, `%` is a true modulus operator, not a remainder, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 16):

## Matlab, 101 <s>105</s> bytes

Thanks a lot to @beaker for his suggestion to use `polyval` instead if `base2dec`. That allowed me to

- save 4 bytes;
- greatly simplify the generalization to arbitrary base (see below) and save 22 bytes there; and most of all,
- helped me realize that the code for the general case was wrong (leading zeros were not being removed). The code and the graphs are correct now.

Code:

```
function y=f(y)
x=+num2str(y);while numel(x)>1
x=polyval(abs(diff(x)),10);y=y+x;x=+dec2base(x,10);end
```

Example:

```
>> f(8675309)
ans =
     8898683
```

### Bonus: arbitrary base

A small generalization allows one to use an arbitrary number base, not necessarily decimal:

- Arbitrary base from 2 to 10, **<s>108</s> 104 bytes**

  ```
  function y=f(y,b)
  x=+dec2base(y,b);while numel(x)>1
  x=polyval(abs(diff(x)),b);y=y+x;x=+dec2base(x,b);end
  ```

  The reason why this works only for base up to `10` is that Matlab's `dec2base` function uses digits `0`, `1`, ..., `9`, `A`, `B`, ..., and there's a jump in character (ASCII) codes from `9` to `A`.
- Arbitrary base from 2 to 36, **124 <s>146</s> bytes**

  The jump from `9` to `A` referred to above needs special treatment. The maximum base is `36` as per Matlab's `dec2base` function.

  ```
  function y=f(y,b)
  x=+dec2base(y,b);x(x>57)=x(x>57)-7;while numel(x)>1
  x=abs(diff(x));x=x(find(x,1):end);y=y+polyval(x,b);end
  ```

This is how the dentist's staircases look for different bases:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is what I would have done... time to think of another answer lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng :-) Thanks

Comment: @BetaDecay Thanks! :-) They're pretty indeed

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
ri_{\s2ew::-:zsi_@+}h
```

Note that this program exits with an error, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781).

With the Java interpreter, errors can be suppressed by closing STDERR. If you try this code online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_%7B%5Cs2ew%3A%3A-%3Azsi_%40%2B%7Dh&input=8675309), ignore all output before the last line.

*Thanks to @Sp3000 for pointing out an error in the original revision.*

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off 1 byte.*

#### Example run

```
$ cjam digit-difference.cjam 2>&- <<< 8675309     
8898683
```

#### How it works

```
ri_   e# Read an integer (I) from STDIN and push a copy (A).
{     e# Do:
  \   e#   Swap I on top of A.
  s   e#   Cast I to string.
      e#   For example, 123 -> "123".
  2ew e#   Push the overlapping slices of length 2 (pair of adjacent digits).
  ::- e#   Replace each pair by its difference.
  :z  e#   Apply absolute value to each difference.
  si  e#   Cast to string, then to integer. This is the new I.
      e#   For example, [1 2 3] -> "123" -> 123.
  _   e#   Push a copy of I.
  @   e#   Rotate A on top of the copy of I.
  +   e#   Add I to A, updating A.
}h    e# While A is truthy, repeat the loop.
```

**A** will always be truthy when checked by `h`. However, once **I** is a single-digit integer, `2ew` will fail with an error after consuming the array it was called on. This leaves only the desired result on the stack, which is printed before exiting.

Comment: Posted in 7 minutes flat :O

Answer (score 11):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <s>176</s> <s>134</s> <s>127</s> <s>119</s> <s>103</s> <s>97</s> <s>88</s> <s>82</s> <s>79</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 1 byte and paving the way for 2 more.*

This could probably still be shortened, but hey, it beats <s>Java</s> <s>Matlab</s> Python...

```
?
_
)/:}+{:`};!
9       "
_ :}-"" :_10
;;{: `" "  :
  {  (_:/=%}
  0+;`"
```

[Try it online.](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PwpfCikvOn0rezpgfTshCjkgICAgICAgIgpfIDp9LSIiIDpfMTAKOzt7OiBgIiAiICA6CiAgeyAgKF86Lz0lfQogIDArO2Ai&input=ODY3NTMwOQ)

This [terminates with an error](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error/4781#4781) but the error message is written to STDERR (which is why you don't see it in TIO).

The implementation is fairly straight-forward. We add the current value to a running total. If the current value was greater than `9`, we compute its base-10 digits (via repeated div-mod), and form a new number from the absolute differences. If we get to `9` or less, we print the running total.

The digits of the current number are collected on the auxiliary stack with the most significant digit on top.

Well, the fancy implementation of `abs(...)` I had here turned out to be ridiculously complicated compared to the new solution... I'll add an updated explanation when I'm done golfing this further.

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), <s>81</s> 60 bytes

```julia
n->(s=n;while n>9 s+=n=int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))end;s)
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(n::Int)
    # Initialize a sum to the input
    s = n

    while n > 9
        # Get absolute values of the pairwise differences of the
        # digits of n, join as a string, convert it to an integer,
        # and reassign n
        n = int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))

        # ["$n"...] actually splits n as a string into a vector
        # of its characters, but the difference between ASCII
        # codes is the same as the difference between the numbers
        # so it works as expected

        # Add the new n to the running sum
        s += n
    end

    # Return the sum
    return s
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCoQwEEbh3lMMssUEMcRSJbmIbKHo4Ej4FaPs8bP56veON@qcxWe0gZPH@Ns1boTQU2o8vOLh41TwvCReVYSn@oPaWvs1xYZ1TCbLeZOSgrqhc85VVFx3eSNYWI2pSpj/)

Saved 21 bytes thanks to feersum and Glen O!

Comment: Is there any reason `ndigits(n)>1` is different than `n>9` ?

Comment: Suggestion: `int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))` saves 9 bytes. Switch to `n>9` as suggested by feersum for another 9 bytes saved. Save three more bytes by performing both assignments in the while loop in one step (and removing the extra, now unnecessary semicolon): `n->(s=n;while n>9 s+=n=int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))end;s)`

Comment: @feersum Um, nope. Thanks!

Comment: @GlenO Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Java - 300 bytes

Golfed Version

```
static Long t=new Scanner(System.in).nextLong();static char[]c=t.toString().toCharArray();public static void main(String[]z){while(c.length>1)s();System.out.print(t);}static void s(){String s="";for(int i=0;i<c.length-1;)s+=Math.abs(c[i]-c[++i]);Long a=new Long(s);t+=a;c=a.toString().toCharArray();}
```

Ungolfed / Full version

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitDifference {

    static Long t = new Scanner(System.in).nextLong();
    static char[] c = t.toString().toCharArray();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while( c.length > 1 )
            s();
        System.out.print(t);
    }

    static void s(){
        String s="";
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length-1;)
            s += Math.abs(c[i]-c[++i]);
        Long a = new Long(s);
        t += a;
        c = a.toString().toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Loovjo, Cheers..

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This can still be golfed a lot. I haven't looked at the logic much but: 1) Pull all of this into one function since you don't really need a separate one (or a full program/class for that matter) 2) Get rid of the `static`s after pulling them in 3) `(a+"")` is generally the same as `a.toString()`, but shorter 4) You don't need a Scanner if it's just a function, simply take a long as input.

Comment: For example, without changing much of the working, and just removing cruft, it's around 164: `long f(long t){long a=t;char[]c;while((c=(a+"").toCharArray()).length>1){String s="";for(int i=0;i<c.length-1;)s+=Math.abs(c[i]-c[++i]);t+=a=new Long(s);}return t;}
`

Comment: @Geobits, that was amazing buddy. I'm new to Code Golf, so I'll try to improve my codign efficiency. Cherrs..

Answer (score 5):

## [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html), <s>37</s> <s>32</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
+/(10/{%x*x}1_-':.:'$)\
```

In action:

```
  +/(10/{%x*x}1_-':.:'$)\8675309
8898683

  (+/(10/{%x*x}1_-':.:'$)\)'!20
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27
```

K5 has a few features which are well suited to this- "encode" and "decode" can perform base conversion, each-pair (`':`) pairs up sequential elements in a list and fixed point scan (`\`) can produce the iterated sequence until it stops changing. The lack of a primitive `abs()` leads to some unsightly bulk in the form of `{(x;-x)x<0}'`, though.

### Edit:

Instead of `{(x;-x)x<0}'`, I can (somewhat wastefully) take the square root of the square of the sequence (`{%x*x}`, saving 5 bytes.

### Edit 2:

Inspired by @maurinus' APL solution, I can replace the "decode" (`((#$x)#10)\x`) with evaluating each character of the string representation of the number- `.:'$x`! This also lets me use a tacit form of the whole expression, saving additional characters.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 87 bytes

```
f=lambda n:n and n+f(int('0'+''.join(`abs(int(a)-int(b))`for a,b in zip(`n`,`n`[1:]))))
```

Recursively adds the current number and takes the digits differences. Lots of converting between numbers and strings. Probably can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```
Tr@FixedPointList[FromDigits@*Abs@*Differences@*IntegerDigits,#]&
```

I'm open to suggestions here.

Comment: `Tr@FixedPointList[FromDigits@*Abs@*Differences@*IntegerDigits,#]&`

Comment: @alephalpha Interesting concept, creating extra zeroes...

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>55</s> 48 bytes

```julia
h=n->(n>9&&h(int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))))+n
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function h(n)
  if n>9
    # If multiple digits, find the digit difference...
    digitdiff=int(join(abs(diff(["$n"...]))))
    # ... recurse the function...
    downsum=h(digitdiff)
    # ... and return the sum so far (working up from the bottom)
    return downsum+n
  else
    # If single digit, no further recursion, return the current number
    return n
  end
end
```

Essentially, this recurses down to the single-digit level (where no digit difference can be performed), then sums back up as it exits the recursion, level by level.

Answer (score 4):

## APL (22)

```
{⍵≤9:⍵⋄⍵+∇10⊥|2-/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

Explanation:

- `⍵≤9:⍵`: if ⍵ ≤ 9, return ⍵ unchanged.
- `⍎¨⍕⍵`: convert ⍵ to a string, then evaluate each character
- `2-/`: subtract every two adjacent numbers
- `|`: take the absolute values
- `10⊥`: turn the array into a base-10 number
- `⍵+∇`: call the function recursively with this new value, and add the result to the input

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 140 bytes

`d` does the job.

```
import Data.Char
d n=sum.m(read.m intToDigit).fst.span(/=[]).iterate s.m digitToInt.show$n
s l@(h:t)=snd$span(==0)$m abs$zipWith(-)l t
m=map
```

Does anyone know how to avoid importing the long conversion functions?

Comment: `intToDigit` is `toEnum.(+48)` and `digitToInt` is `(\i->fromEnum i-48)`. You can also turn `s` to a pointfree version with  `=<<` in list context: `s=snd.span(==0).m abs.(zipWith(-)=<<tail)`. Finally, `(==0)` is `(<1)`, because we're working with non-negative integers.

Comment: ... oh, and if `s` is pointfree, there's not need to give it a name. Call it directly: `iterate(snd.span ... tail))`

Comment: ... it's me again to correct a mistake in my first comment: `=<<` is used in function context, not list context, sorry.

Comment: Brilliant! Also, is it common procedure here to use GHC extensions? `NoMonomorphismRestriction` will let me have `d` pointfree, too.

Comment: Isn't `chr.(+48)` even shorter than `toEnum.(+48)`, and `(\i->ord i-48)` than `(\i->fromEnum i-48)`?

Comment: `chr` and `ord` are both in `Data.Char`, so you can't omit the `import`. Compiler flags are counted as bytes, too, so `NoMonomorphismRestriction` increases your score by 25.

Comment: disappointing, but good to know!

Answer (score 3):

## K5, 50 bytes

```
+/{(r;x)@~r:.,/"0",{$(0;-r;r)@(~^r)+0<r:x-y}':$x}\
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 125 bytes

I used to like the shortness of regex until I tried to use it for this challenge...`re.findall('\d\d',s,overlapped=True)` is *not* on ;)

```py
s=input()
p=int
x=p(s)
while p(s)>9:g=str(s);s=p(''.join(str(abs(p(g[i])-p(g[i+1])))for i in range(len(g)-1)));x+=s 
print(x)
```

Cheers @Todd :)

Comment: You can perform inplace addition on an integer rather than a list which will remove the need to square brackets and the final sum. 
's=p(input())'
will allow you the remove the int conversion on the while loop and assignment to x.
Also consider looping through the zip of g and g[1:] which should save some bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 73 bytes

```
t=n=>(b=10,M=Math).ceil(n&&n+t((j=n=>n>9&&M.abs(n%b-n/b%b)+b*j(n/b))(n)))
```

This isn't getting any shorter :/ I'll try more approaches but this is the shortest one so far

Comment: If you just leave it as an anonymous function instead of assigning it to `t` it's still valid and saves you 2 bytes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes but I'm using recursion so I need to name it

Comment: Oh, missed that, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser (but not Chrome as it still does not support the spread operator `...`) MS Edge maybe?

```js
f=n=>n&&(n+=r='',[...n].map(d=>(r+=d>p?d-p:p-d,p=d),p=n[0]),+n+f(+r))

function test()
{
  var i=+I.value
  O.innerHTML = i+' -> '+f(i) + '\n' + O.innerHTML 
}
```

```html
<input id=I value=8675309><button onclick=test()>-></button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Alternative, using *array comprehension* that is now targeted EcmaScript 2016 (ES7), 67 bytes:

```
f=n=>n&&(n+=r='',p=n[0],[for(d of n)(r+=d>p?d-p:p-d,p=d)],+n+f(+r))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>12</s> 7 bytes

```
≬¯ṅ⌊İ∑+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiazCr+G5heKMisSw4oiRKyIsIiIsIjg2NzUzMDkiXQ==)

*-5 bytes thanks to allxy*

### How?

```
≬¯ṅ⌊İ∑+ # full program
≬¯ṅ⌊    # Three element lambda
 ¯      # Deltas (consecutive differences of digits)
  ṅ     # Join by nothing
   ⌊    # Convert to integer
    İ   # Apply this lambda on the (implicit) input and collect unique values
     ∑  # Summate
      + # Add to (implicit) input
```

Comment: [7](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiazCr+G5heKMisSw4oiRKyIsIiIsIjg2NzUzMDkiXQ==). I find it very interesting that `⌊` parses it the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 49 bytes

```perl
$\+=$_;s/.(?=(.))/abs$&-$1/ge;s/^0+|.$//g&&redo}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJd66WF9Pw95WQ09TUz8xqVhFTVfFUD89FSgcZ6Bdo6eir5@uplaUmpJfW/3/v4WZuamxgeW//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULAA)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 70 bytes

```
 +/([:10&#.[:(2|@:-/\])[:10&(]#:~[#~[:>.[^.])])`]@.(11&>)^:a:".(1!:1)3
```

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB <del>(141)</del>(137)

> **EDIT:** 4 bytes less, thanks to @Andras

```
function[s j]=n(T,b,c),if(T/b>9),u=fix(T/10);[x e]=n(T,b*10,0);y=n(u,b,0);[w z]=n(u,b,c);s=abs(x-y);j=s+e+10*c*z;else,s=mod(T,10);j=s;end
```

- This doest beat @LuisMendo 's answer but atleast I could reduce execution time, which by, I would have just tried to diversify ways of tackling this problem.
- I could reduce it more but as I go for less time, i waste more bytes, so here is the principle:

The program is summing up digits of same row before inlined digits , it does mean it used integer division "n/10" log_10(n) times only, complexity is O(N).

If `n= a b c d`

```
a          b           c           d
   |a-b|       |b-c|       |c-d|
    ||a-b|-|b-c|| ||b-c|-|c-d||
   ....
```

My program calculates:

```
a+|a-b| + | |a-b|-|b-c| |  +  |  | |a-b|-|b-c| | - | |b-c|-|c-d| |  |
+10*(
b+|b-c| + | |b-c|-|c-d| |
+10*(
c+|c-d|
+10*(
d
)
)
)
```

### Usage:

```
  [a b]=n(13652,1,1)
```

a =

1

```
 b =

   16098
```

Comment: You can spare 4 bytes by omitting the optional `,end` of the `function` declaration.

Comment: Please consider revising the grammar of your post.  I can't quite understand what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 143 bytes

**Code:**

```
q(X,N):-X<9,N=0;A is abs(X mod 10-X//10 mod 10),Y is X//10,q(Y,M),N is A+M*10.
r(X,N):-X<9,N=X;q(X,Y),r(Y,M),N is X+M.
p(X):-r(X,N),write(N).
```

**Explained:**

```
q(X,N):-X<9,N=0;                                                         % If only one digit, the difference is 0
        A is abs(X mod 10-X//10 mod 10),Y is X//10,q(Y,M),N is A+M*10.   % Else, the difference is the difference between the last 2 digits + the recursive difference of the number without the last digit
r(X,N):-X<9,N=X;                                                         % If we only have 1 digit the final answer is that digit
        q(X,Y),r(Y,M),N is X+M.                                          % Else, the final answer is the current number + the recursive difference of that number
p(X):-r(X,N),write(N).
```

**q** does the calculations that convert a number into it's Digit Difference.
**r** recursively calls **q** and sums up the results to find the Digit Difference Sum.

**p** is the entry point. Takes a number, calls **r** and prints the answer.

**Example:**

```
>p(8675309).
8898683
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/FEbBzrgH.pl).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 198 bytes

```
<?$x=$t=$_GET['V'];function z($x){global$t;for($i=0;$i<strlen($x)-1;$i++){$z=str_split($x);$r.=str_replace('-','',$z[$i]-$z[$i+1]);}$r=ltrim($r,'0');$t+=$r;return strlen($r)>1?z($r):0;}z($x);echo$t;
```

Ungolfed

```
<?
$x=$t=$_GET['V']; // Gets the value from input
function z($x){
    global$t;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($x)-1;$i++){
        $z=str_split($x); //Turns the string into an array
        $r.=str_replace('-','',$z[$i]-$z[$i+1]); // Sums the two values and removes the minus signal
    }
    $r=ltrim($r,'0'); // Remove trailing zeroes
    $t+=$r; // Adds to global var
    return strlen($r)>1?z($r):0; // Checks the size of the string. If >1, calls the function again
}

z($x);
echo$t;
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 56 bytes

```perl6
{[+] $_,{+.comb.rotor(2=>-1)».map((*-*).abs).join}…0} # 56 bytes
```

usage:

```perl6
my &code = {...} # insert code from above

(180..190).map: &code;
# (259 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 280)

say code 8675309; # 8898683
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ạƝḌ$ƬS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4bqhxp3huIwkxqxT/zg2NzUzMDk7MjDhuLbCpDvDhyTigqxH/w)

### How it works

```
ạƝḌ$ƬS - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
   $Ƭ  - Repeat the following until a repeated value, collected intermediate results:
 Ɲ     -   Convert an integer to digits, and on overlapping pairs:
ạ      -     Take the absolute difference
  Ḍ    -   Convert from digits to an integer
     S - Take the sum of these values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ΣU¡ȯdẊ≠d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr///Oo1XCocivZOG6iuKJoGT///84Njc1MzA5)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èìä'a}hN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=yOzkJ2F9aE4&input=MTAyNA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.extras project-euler.common`, <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```factor
[ 0 swap [ [ + ] keep number>digits differences vabs digits>number ] until-zero ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY47DsIwDIZ3TuEdtUJMCFBXxIKEEBNiCKkDgeaB4_C6CksXuFNvQ0pkyY_fn3_5_VVCsqO2e2w3y9ViChckiw0YccGU-FTesAdCHgIL1oG1DODJndOqwNggldIZ42yG8MEkegCZn5605b8OAa8RrcQAs8FgPIK5diyqT2RVTLr1DkYQ7sLDLsUQ9ukT9GCjOSBVtT5qDlBrpZCyx00ceqHXq0ylm2hZN8ULycE-G39Msixz37a5_gA)

- `0 swap` Initialize the sum.
- `[ ... ] until-zero` Call a quotation until its result is 0, dropping the 0 from the stack.
- `[ + ] keep` Add the current summand to our sum.
- `number>digits differences vabs digits>number` Get the next summand.

Answer (score 0):

## C 162 bytes

golfed:

```
main(int argc,char **argv){char *c=argv[1];int u=atoi(c),d;do{while(c[1]!=0){*c=abs(*c-*(c+1))+48;c++;}*c=0;c=argv[1];d=atoi(c);u+=d;}while(d>9);printf("%d",u);}
```

ungolfed:

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *c=argv[1];
    int u=atoi(c),d;

    do
    {
        while(c[1]!=0)
        {
            *c=abs(*c-*(c+1))+48;
            c++;
        }

        *c=0;
        c=argv[1];
        d=atoi(c);
        u+=d;
    }
    while(d>9);

    printf("%d\n",u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 134 Bytes

#### Code

```r
f=function(x){z=x;while(z>9){n=seq(nchar(z));z=abs(diff(strtoi(substring(z,n,n))));z=sum(z*10**(rev(seq(length(z)))-1));x=x+z};cat(k)}
```

Test it [online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=iX6pcHCs&version=3).

#### Ungolfed

```r
f=function(x){
  z=x;
  while(z>9){
    n=seq(nchar(z));
    z=abs(diff(strtoi(substring(z,n,n))));
    z=sum(z*10**(rev(seq(length(z)))-1));
    x=x+z
  };
  cat(x)
}
```

Here is the plot of the difference of the "Digit Difference Sum of a Number" series from f(1) to f(1m). Just because I love to diff.
[image]

#### Plot code

```r
s <- seq(1,100000)
serie <- sapply(s,f)
plot(diff(ts(serie)),xlab="",ylab="")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
λ£üαJï}þO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//867wqPDvM6xSsOvfcO@T///MTEwMTY) or [verify the first 1001 test cases](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX/4oKEw53Otf/Ou8Kjw7zOsUrDr33Dvk///w).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately the *Cumulative fixed-point* builtin `.Γ` (to reduce until the result no longer changes and collecting all intermediate results) won't include the starting value. In addition, we'll have to remove the trailing empty string value. So it would be 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage): `.ΓüαJï}¨O+` - [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79zkw3vObfQ6vL720Ap/7f//DQ0NDM0A).

So using this unorthodox method with the recursive environment saves a byte in the end:

```python
λ      # Start a recursive environment,
 £     # to calculate the values in the range [a(0),a(implicit input)]
       # Starting with a(0) = (implicit) input
       # Where every following a(n) is calculated as:
       #  (implicitly push a(n-1))
  ü    #  For each overlapping digit:
   α   #   Get the absolute difference
    J  #  Join these differences together to a string
     ï #  Remove potential leading 0s (by casting to an integer)
}      # After the recursive environment
 þ     # Remove all empty trailing strings by only keeping numbers
  O    # Sum those numbers together
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.4](https://julialang.org), 47 bytes

```
!n=n+(n>9&&!evalpoly(10,abs.(diff(digits(n)))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6Fjf1FfNs87Q18uws1dQUU8sScwrycyo1DA10EpOK9TRSMtPSgER6ZkmxRp4mCEC1GTsUZ-SXKyhamJmbGhtYcnGl5RcpZCpk5ikYWBkaGBhwKQBBQVFmXklOnoZipiZXal4KRCvMZgA)