# Cover up zeroes in a list

Tags: code-golf, array

Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34041614)

As input you will be given a non-empty list of integers, where the first value is guaranteed to be non-zero. To construct the output, walk from the start of the list, outputting each non-zero value along the way. When you encounter a zero, instead repeat the value you most recently added to the output.

You may write a program or function, and have input/output take any convenient format which does not encode extra information, as long as is still an ordered sequence of integers. If outputting from a program, you may print a trailing newline. Except for this trailing newline, your output should be an acceptable input for your submission.

The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test Cases

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9] -> [1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, 0, 5, 0, 0, -7] -> [-1, -1, 5, 5, 5, -7]
[23, 0, 0, -42, 0, 0, 0] -> [23, 23, 23, -42, -42, -42, -42]
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[-1234] -> [-1234]
```

Comment: A bit of trivia: The name for this operation in the world of statistics is LOCF (last observation carried forward) imputation.

Comment: What happens if the input was `[0,0]`?

Comment: @KριτικσιΛίθος "...where the first value is guaranteed to be non-zero"

Comment: What if the input is `[1,01]`? Using, issac's Pyth answer, compare [this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mJ%7CdJQ&input=%5B1%2C1%5D&debug=0) and [this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mJ%7CdJQ&input=%5B1%2C01%5D&debug=0).

Comment: @Eridan `01` is not a valid integer in Pyth input, so isaac doesn't have to account for that. Other answers can accept input like that if they want, just so long as they are consistent (like how isaac's answer will never produce that list as output)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I don't know the mechanics of Pyth, so I appreciate the explanation, thanks.

Comment: Can we error out when finished?

Comment: @tfbninja As long as the error [doesn't affect your output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/31625), you can do whatever you would like. This is a site-wide default, so feel free to assume it is alright in the future!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
mJ|dJQ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mJ%7CdJQ&input=%5B1%2C+0%2C+2%2C+0%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+0%2C+5%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+9%5D&debug=0)

`m ... Q` means this maps a function over the input. The function being mapped is `J|dJ`. That means `J = d or J` in Python, since `J` is implicity assigned to the following value on first use. Unlike Python, assignment expressions return the value assigned in Pyth, so the map returns each successive value of `J`, as desired.

Answer (score 25):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
o@\
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=b0Bc&input=&args=WzIzLCAwLCAwLCAtNDIsIDAsIDAsIDBd)

#### How it works

```
o      Take the logical OR of its arguments.
 @     Reverse the argument order of the link to the left.
  \    Do a cumulative reduce, using the link to the left.
```

Comment: My brain cannot comprehend... Dennis has finally found a way to permanently out golf us. Like he hadn't already. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: The explanation no longer aligns with the program

Answer (score 19):

### Ruby, 25 bytes

```
->a{a.map{|x|x==0?a:a=x}}
```

This is actually really evil.

Specifically, the snippet `x==0 ? a : (a=x)`.

If I had used any other variable name for `a` (the previous nonzero value)—let's say `y`—I would have to declare it outside the `map` (because `y=x` would only have a scope of inside that single `map` iteration). That would use four chars more (`y=0;`).

But if I use the variable name `a`... yep, you guessed it. I'm actually reassigning to *the argument that we got as input* (the original array).

`map` doesn't care because it only cares about the *original* value of the thing its being called on, so this actually works.

Answer (score 18):

### Haskell, 21 bytes

```haskell
a%0=a
a%b=b
scanl1(%)
```

The (anonymous) function we make is in the last line. The first two lines define a helper function.

```haskell
scanl1(%) [1,0,2,0,7,7,7,0,5,0,0,0,9]
[1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,5,9]
```

The binary function `%` outputs the second argument, unless it's `0`, in which case it outputs the first argument instead. `scanl1` iterates this function over the input list, outputting the result at each step.

Answer (score 13):

### J, 8 bytes

```
{:@-.&0\
```

This is a unary function, invoked as follows.

```
   f =: {:@-.&0\
   f 2 0 0 4 0 _1 0
2 2 2 4 4 _1 _1
```

### Explanation

```
{:@-.&0\
       \  Map over non-empty prefixes:
   -.      remove all occurrences
     &0    of the number 0 and
{:@        take the last element.
```

Comment: Can you replicate by absolute value instead of removing 0s?

Comment: @ThomasKwa That was my first attempt. It's ``{:@(#~|)\``, so one byte longer.

Answer (score 13):

## Sed, 8

```
/^0$/g
h
```

- `/^0$/` matches a zero on a line - if so `g` copies the hold space to the pattern space
- `h` copies the pattern space to the hold space

Integers are newline separated.  e.g:

```
$ printf -- "-1\n0\n5\n0\n0\n7\n" | sed -f zerocover.sed
-1
-1
5
5
5
7
$
```

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript ES6, 19 bytes

```
s=>s.map(i=>p=i||p)
```

Straightforward solution, loop through input, assign `p` to current element `i` or to `p` if `i` is `0` and output it.

Example run (assigning anonymous function to `f`):

```
>> f([1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9])
<< Array [1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Whenever [I run this](http://server.vihan.ml/p/esfiddle/?code=(%20s%3D%3Es.map(i%3D%3Ep%3Di%7C%7Cp)%20)(%5B1%2C%200%2C%202%2C%200%2C%207%2C%207%2C%207%2C%200%2C%205%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%209%5D)) I get an error saying "can't find variable p"

Comment: @Downgoat That's because the interpreter is a Strict Mode only interpreter. If you don't run that code in strict mode, it should work.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 ohh,r okay

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Strict mode is silly.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 It's not silly. It's very useful; it makes sure your code is not ambiguous, and will work even with a major update, and doesn't use undefined behaviour, etc. But what's silly is enabling it by default, since Strict mode doesn't specify a way to turn itself off, and if you don't put the strict mode string at the beginning, you don't want it and/or are code-golfing.

Answer (score 9):

### Dyalog APL, <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
(⊃0~⍨,⍨)\
```

Inspired by @Zgarb's J answer.

```
(⊃0~⍨,⍨)\      Monadic function:
        \      Cumulative reduce by
(⊃0~⍨,⍨)       the dyadic function:
     ,⍨           Arguments concatenated in reverse order
  0~⍨             With zeroes removed
 ⊃                Take the first element
```

Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%7B%u2283%u233D%u2375%7E0%7D%A8%2C%5C%29%20%AF1%200%205%200%200%20%AF7&run).

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 15 bytes

```
+`(\S+) 0
$1 $1
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2AoXFMrKSAwCiQxICQx&input=MSAwIDIgMCA3IDcgNyAwIDUgMCAwIDAgOSAxIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAtMSAwIDUgMCAwIC03IDIzIDAgMCAtNDIgMCAwIDAgMSAyIDMgNCAtMTIzNA)

Repeatedly replaces a number followed by a zero with twice that number until the string stops changing.

Answer (score 7):

### Java, 78

```
int[]f(int[]a){for(int i=-1,b=i;++i<a.length;a[i]=b=a[i]==0?b:a[i]);return a;}
```

Here we just keep track of the last non-zero and shove it in where appropriate. Seems like the obvious way to do it.

Comment: 76, took off a couple:
 
`int[]f(int[]a){for(int i=0;++i<a.length;a[i]=a[i]==0?a[i-1]:a[i]);return a;}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7BTsMwDL3vK3xstCzqBmJAqBAfwGnHqgfTtcUlS6fEHZqqfnvJEjggPdnP78n26/GCm/74tZzHD0M11Aa9h3ckC9Nq9St6RqZ6Ictl1WaxoZjawd04UJHr9ZpeUJnGdvypsaSqiKXIX0PfbKvn2yi0a3h0FlDPy7/TcBnoCKfwNTuwI9uVFaDrvIAJDlfPzUkNI6tzsNjYrA@h1chk1JtzePWKh7SWtZltviEmnLYScgkPEvaRBDxJCOJOwl2y7v@MgMT3EY9J2SVvFkJomGFefgA "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 29 bytes

```python
while 1:x=input()or x;print x
```

Takes input as numbers given one per line, and outputs in the same format. Terminates with error after finishing.

Using the short-circuiting nature of `or`, the variable `x` is updated to the input, unless that input is 0 (which is Falsey), in which case it remains its current value. Then, `x` is printed. Note that since the first list value is nonzero, `x` is not evaluated in the right hand side before it is assigned.

Comment: This is 6 bytes in Pyth, and suppresses the error: `#\nJ|EJ`

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, 8 bytes

```
t.u|YNQ0
```

Uses `.u` (cumulative reduce) by `|` (Python's `or`), with base case 0.

Comment: @isaacg It seems like `.u` is longer even if `J` and `K` are tied up. Is it ever optimal?

Comment: It was (at least afaik) [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58330/31625). It usually helps when you would want all the results for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 54 bytes

```
[X,0|T]+[X,X|Y]:-[X|T]+[X|Y].
[X|T]+[X|Y]:-T+Y.
[]+[].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PzpCx6AmJFYbSEfURMZa6UZHQLhAjh4XEsdKN0Q7EigC5MbqAfUZ6hgAoREQGwKhrlmsdoQeAA)

### Explanation

I'm really happy with this answer.

First we say that the empty list is the solution of the empty list:

```
[]+[].
```

Then we say that `[X,X|Y]` is the solution of `[X,0|T]`, if by removing the second entry of each of the remaining solutions.

```
[X,0|T]+[X,X|Y]:-[X|T]+[X|Y].
```

Lastly we say that any thing left over is valid if they start with the same value and the rest of the the two lists match each other.

If that explanation isn't working for you here is the code translated into Haskell:

```hs
g(a:0:x)=a:g(a:x)
g(a:x)=a:g x
g x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10j0crAqkLTNtEKxKzQ5IJQIL5CBRcQ21b8z03MzLMtKMrMK1FJjzbUMdIxAEPj2P8A)

Comment: Very concise! I like how some functional and logic programming languages allow you to do such a literal translation of the rules. It's such a natural way to write it!

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PzpCx6AmJFY70koXyIwAM/W4osEMIBkZa6UbAhYBcmP1gOoNdQyA0AiIDYFQ1yxWO0IPAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
N£U=XªU
```

Pretty simple. Takes input separated by commas. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=TqNVPViqVQ==&input=MSwwLDIsMCw3LDcsNywwLDUsMCwwLDAsOQ==)

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
N£    U=Xª U
NmXYZ{U=X||U

        // Implicit: N = input, U = first item
NmXYZ{  // Map each item X to:
U=Z||U  //  Set U to (X || U) and return.
        //  If X is non-zero, this sets U to X.
        //  Otherwise, this leaves U as the last non-zero we've encountered.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

**4-byte** version:

```
Nå!ª
```

Explanation:

```
Nå!ª
Nå!||
NåXY{Y||X}

        // Implicit: N = input, U = first item
NåXY{   // Cumulatively reduce N; take each item Y and prev value X,
Y||X}   //  and return Y if it is non-zero; return X otherwise.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=TuUhqg==&input=MSwwLDIsMCw3LDcsNywwLDUsMCwwLDAsOQ==)

Comment: Wait, `ª` is OR, rather than `º`? Is `º` AND by any chance?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Nope, `º` is `((`. They were assigned by Unicode value as I found the need for them :P `ª`nd and `º`r is genius though, I might use that for Japt 2.0...

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 38 bytes

Pattern matching repeatedly replaces `...a,0,...` with `...a,a...`

```
#//.{b___,a_/;a!=0,0,e___}:>{b,a,a,e}&
```

Answer (score 5):

## Matlab, 41 <s>46</s> bytes

This is inspired in my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043697/2586922), with the following differences:

1. Use logical indexing instead of `nonzeros`.
2. Double logical negation instead of comparing with `0`.
3. The transpose can be removed, as the output format is flexible
4. Removing an intermediate variable.

Thanks to [Tom Carpenter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65770/cover-up-zeroes-in-a-list/65797#comment159390_65797) for item 4, and for his suggestion to use a program instead of a function; together these allowed a reduction of 5 bytes.

```
x=input('');u=x(~~x);disp(u(cumsum(~~x)))
```

Example:

```
>> x=input('');u=x(~~x);disp(u(cumsum(~~x)))
[4 0 3 2 0 5 6 0]
     4     4     3     2     2     5     6     6
```

Comment: You can save one byte by converting it to a program - use ```x=input('')``` instead of the function declaration, and ```disp(u(t)``` instead of the ```y=``` bit. Also, you can save four more bytes by getting rid of the ```t``` variable, yielding ```x=input('');u=x(~~x);disp(u(cumsum(~~x)))``` for 41.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks a lot! Edited

Comment: I don't have Matlab, but `@(x)x(~~x)(cumsum(~~x))` works in Octave.

Comment: @alephalpha Matlab doesn't allow iterated indexing.

Answer (score 5):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki), 8 bytes

```
IE;:Z~:N
```

Input and output are newline separated numbers.

Explanation:

```
I         push next integer to stack
 E;       halt if EOF
   :Z~    remove top stack element if 0
      :N  print top stack element while also keeping it on the stack
          wrap around code implicitly
```

[Try it online here.](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/#)

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript, 10 bytes

```
~{1$or}*]`
```

This program takes input from stdin, in the form of a GolfScript array literal (e.g. `[1 0 2 0]`), and writes its output to stdout in the same format (e.g. `[1 1 2 2]`).

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBDYW5uZWQgaW5wdXQ6CjsiWzEgMiAwIDMgMCAwIDQgNSAtMSAtMiAwIC0xMjM0IDBdIgoKIyBQcm9ncmFtOgp%2BezEkb3J9Kl1g)

A function (taking and returning a GolfScript array) would be three bytes longer, due to the need to wrap it in a block and assign it to a symbol:

```
{[{1$or}*]}:f
```

Of course, if only the function *body* (i.e. `[{1$or}*]`) is counted, then I can actually save one byte compared to the stand-alone program.

Comment: Perhaps not surprisingly, the new, shorter version turned out very similar to [Dennis's CJam entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65778). It wins by one byte because GolfScript reads the input automatically, and thus doesn't need an extra command for that.

Answer (score 4):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
$I?.nd?xdN
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24I%3F%2End%3FxdN&input=-1%2C%200%2C%205%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20-7) Input can be given as in the question, but **without brackets**.

#### Explanation

```
$I      Push the length of the input on the stack.
  ?.    If this is 0, stop. Otherwise, continue.

nd        Take number from input and duplicate it.
  ?x      If this number is 0, dump the top of stack.
    dN    Duplicate the top of stack and output as number
```

Minkolang is toroidal, so this loops around to the beginning and keeps going until it hits the `.` and stops.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```r
function(x)zoo::na.locf(x*(x|NA))
```

This is an unnamed function that accepts a vector and returns a vector. It requires the `zoo` package to be installed. Note that it doesn't require `zoo` to be attached to the namespace since we're referencing it directly.

The name for this operation in the world of statistics is LOCF imputation, where LOCF stands for Last Observation Carried Forward. To accomplish this in R, we can use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package, which replaces `NA` values with the last known non-`NA` value. We just have to replace the zeros in the input with `NA`s first.

To do that, we use `x|NA`, which will be `TRUE` when `x != 0` and `NA` otherwise. If we multiply this by `x`, the `TRUE` elements are replaced by the corresponding elements of `x` and the `NA`s stay `NA`, thereby replacing all zeros. This is then passed to `zoo::na.locf` which gives us exactly what we want.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to flodel!

Answer (score 4):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o),  31 bytes

```
[[I',T%T/]{n#}d]{n.{:V}{;V}?}d]
```

This takes an input separated by `,` and outputs the same list in `[]`.

```
7,0,3,0,0,2,-50,0,0 => [7,7,3,3,3,2,-50,-50,-50]
```

Explanation:

```
[                             ] Put result into array
 [I',T%T/]{n#}d]                Format input into array of numbers
                {n.{:V}{;V}?}d  Fill in zeros (see below for how this works)
```

## 17 bytes

```
I~]{n.{:V}{;V}?}d
```

Takes input as a list of numbers separated by spaces using postfix notation and can only handle single digit hexadecimal numbers. Negatives are postfixed with `_`.

```
5 4 0 0 1 0 0 => 5 4 4 4 1 1 1
A 3 0 0 1 B 0 => 10 3 3 3 1 11 11
67* 0 0 78* 0 => 42 42 42 56 56
67*_ 4 3_ 0 0 => -42 4 -3 -3 -3
```

Explanation:

```
I~]               Puts input into integer array
   {           }d For each number in the input
    n.{;V}{:V}?   If the number is 0, push V
                  If not, set V to the number
```

Comment: You can save two bytes with `I~]{n.{:V}{;V}?}d`. I wonder if `d` should just put the value on the stack instead of `n`...

Comment: Are you sure O can handle this? I can't find the way to pass it -42 satisfying the “your output should be an acceptable input for your submission” requirement.

Comment: @manatwork I've got a better version now that works for `-42`, but it adds brackets around the output.

Answer (score 4):

## , 7 chars / 12 bytes

```
ïⓜa=$⋎a
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B1%2C%200%2C%202%2C%200%2C%207%2C%207%2C%207%2C%200%2C%205%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%209%5D&code=%C3%AF%E2%93%9Ca%3D%24%E2%8B%8Ea)</kbd>

### Explanation

```
        // implicit: ï = input array
ïⓜ     // map over input
  a=    // set a to:
    $   // (if element is truthy (not 0)) element itself
     ⋎a // else whatever a was set to before
        // implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

### R, 36 bytes

```
function(x)x[cummax(seq(a=x)*(!!x))]
```

Let's see how this works using `x=`

```
c(1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9)
```

as an example. Here, `!!x` will be the logical (True/False) vector:

```
c(T, F, T, F, T, T, T, F, T, F, F, F, T)
```

Also, `seq(a=x)` gives a vector of indices as long as `x`:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

We multiply both, giving:

```
c(1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 13)
```

We take the cumulative maximum:

```
c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13)
```

Finally, we use that last vector as the indices to extract from `x`:

```
c(1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9)
```

Comment: I believe `x[cummax(seq(!x)*!!x]` is 3 bytes shorter and equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 100 bytes

```rust
fn f(i:&[i64])->Vec<i64>{let(mut o,mut l)=(i.to_vec(),0);
for x in&mut o{if *x==0{*x=l}else{l=*x}};o}
```

Stumbled across this challenge, thought I'd try it in my favorite language. Tried using `[T]::windows_mut()` at first, before finding out that [it doesn't exist](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23783). And it might've actually been longer than this. Anyway, it turns out that golfed Rust is very ugly and very not-competitive (especially with all those goshdarned esoterics!)<sup>1</sup>

The newline isn't included in the bytecount; it's only there so you don't have to scroll sideways. It doesn't change the meaning of the code.

Ungolfed:

```rust
fn cover_zeroes(input: &[i64]) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut output = input.to_vec();
    let mut last_nonzero = 0;
    for item in &mut output {
        if *item == 0 {
            *item = last_nonzero;
        }
        else {
            last_nonzero = *item;
        }
    }
    output
}
```

<sub><sup>[1] At least it's not as bad as Java.</sup></sub>

Comment: "*At least it's not as bad as Java*"? [Ahem...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66035/14215) ;)

Comment: @Geobits Oh, right. I was counting on you needing that `public static void main` boilerplate…

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
G|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFtueW5w6qOmxv/uNf///4@ONtQx0DECYnMwNNAxBWIQtIzVActBIZCnawiX1jUH8o2MIWwTI7gSQ6BRxjomYMVGxiaxsQA)

scan from left with or.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
q~{1$e|}*]p
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B1%24e%7C%7D*%5Dp&input=%5B23%200%200%20-42%200%200%200%5D)

#### How it works

```
q~             Read and evaluate all input.
  {    }*      Fold; for each element but the first:
   1$e|          Copy the previous element and take their logical OR.
         ]p   Wrap all results in an array and print it.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Powershell, 32 bytes

```
param($x)$x|%{($t=($_,$t)[!$_])}
```

`$x|%{...}` does the script block for each element in `$x`. `($_,$t)` is an array of current element and `$t`, and `[!$_]` means that we use `!$_` to index into the array. The index will be `0` (false) for non-zero elements and `1` (true) when current element is zero, so `$t` will be either current element or `$t`. The parentheses surround the assignment expression so its value is emitted. Without parantheses it would be just a "quiet" assignment to `$t`.

Comment: @TimmyD, you are right, of course. I've added `param($x)` which turns this into a program. The output is a collection of integers which you can submit as a parameter to the program, e.g. `$a = .\program.ps1 1,2,3,4,0,0,5` and then `.\program.ps1 $a` works as expected.

Comment: `$args|%{($p=($_,$p)[!$_])}` - 26 bytes using $args.

Answer (score 3):

## [Milky Way 1.2.1](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 33 bytes

```
:y;=<:&{~<?{0b_^;:3≤_;}1-}^<Ω!
```

This assumes that the list of integers is solely on the stack.

---

#### Explanation

```
:    : :           :              # duplicate the TOS
 y                                # push the length of the TOS
  ;               ;    ;          # swap the TOS and STOS
   =                              # dump a list to the stack
    < <    <                 <    # rotate the stack leftward
        &{~                }      # while loop
            ?{  _     _ }         # if-else statements
              0     3    1        # push an integer
               b                  # == on the TOS and STOS
                 ^          ^     # pop the TOS without output
                     ≤            # rotate the top N stack elements leftward
                          -       # subtract the TOS from the STOS
                              Ω   # push a list made of the top N stack elements
                               !  # output the TOS
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that TOS and STOS mean Top of Stack and Second-to-Top of Stack, is this right?

Comment: Yep @FlagAsSpam

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 33 bytes

```julia
g(x,a=0)=[(i!=0&&(a=i);a)for i=x]
```

This is a function `g` that accepts an array and returns an array. We start a temporary variable `a` at 0. For each element `i` of the input, if `i` isn't 0 then we assign `a` to `i`. If `i` is 0, `a` doesn't change at that iteration. We use `a` as the value in that position in the output array.

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
*.map: {$_=($^a||$_)}
```

usage:

```perl6
# store the Whatever lambda as a subroutine
# just so that we don't have to repeat it
my &code = *.map: {$_=($^a||$_)}

say code [1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9];
# (1 1 2 2 7 7 7 7 5 5 5 5 9)

say [-1, 0, 5, 0, 0, -7].&code;
# (-1 -1 5 5 5 -7)

say ([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[-1, 0, 5, 0, 0, -7]).map: &code;
# ((1 1 1 1 1 1) (-1 -1 5 5 5 -7))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
å!ª
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5SGq&input=WzEsMCwyLDAsNyw3LDcsMCw1LDAsMCwwLDld)

```
å!ª     :Implicit input of array
å       :Cumulatively reduce
 !      :Flip the arguments
  ª     :Logical OR
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
εĀiyU}X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NYjDZmVobUR//9Hm@ooGICRkTmY0jWHCRjEAgA)

My first try, using 05AB1E

```
ε       for each y in input
  Āi    if > 0
    yU  save current value in X
  }
  X     push X
        implicitly close for-loop and print list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
*.map($ [R||]=*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0svN7FAQ0UhOqimJtZWS/O/NVdxYqVCmkKufky0npZ9TKy@nmuYo49CWn6RQk5mXmrx/2hDHQUDHQUjMGkOQ0C2KZiEIMtYBV07BZBSQ7BSIySl5mClcGQZywU1EoGQdSMQUKGuIapVuuYQpSBxEIabCpTgijYyhqszMUIzHCQHw2BZFALiJiAbKGsCdw2MD3KHkbEJzGoQEwA)

Maps each element to the reverse logical OR with the previous calculated element. I wish I could do something like `{[\R||] $_}` but the `R` operator doesn't quite work that way.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 21 bytes

```sh
for i;echo $[n=i?i:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCHTOjU5I19BJTrPNtM@0yov9n8tV5qCoYKBghEQGwOxCRdIBVjQQsESKACG//8DAA)

We use `echo` instead of `<<<` because we need to set `n`. Using `<<<$[n=i?i:n]` expands `$[n=i?i:n]` in a subshell, which will prevent `n` from ever being set.

Answer (score 3):

## [k4](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref), 15 bytes

```
{^\?[0=x;0N;x]}
```

---

```
   ?[        ]  / vector conditional ?[cond;true;false]; eg ?[010b;2 2 2;3 3 3] -> 3 2 3
 ^\             / fills nulls (0N) with preceding value
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 44 bytes

```
f(0,B,B).
f(A,_,A).
X*O:-scanl(f,X,0,[_|O]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P03DQMdJx0lTjytNw1EnXscRyIrQ8rfSLU5OzMvRSNOJ0DHQiY6v8Y/V1PtvpasQbQjkGwGxORga6JgCMQhaxipoKfjrKBQUZeaVaPgDVQMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0map&'x->(0=x)?[<=]-><=x]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?0nMHtE)

```
$=>[          ; a function where input is assigned to &
    0         ; push 0 to stack
    map&'x->  ; map over input, assign current elt to x
    (0=x)?    ; is the current element zero?
    [<=]      ; then duplicate top of stack
    ->        ; otherwise,
        <=x   ; push x and duplicate it
]             ; end function
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ʋs|
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS45tKq5ZUpyUXAwVWHBTPdpQR8FAR8EITJrDEJBtCiYhyDIWoh4A)

##### Explanation

```python
Ʋs|  # Implicit input
Ʋ    # Cumulative reduce by:
 s|  #  Swapped logical OR
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
pZ‼l
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FssKoh417MlZUpyUXAwVWnCzNtpQR8FAR8EITJrDEJBtCiYhyDKWC6oOgYBCuoaoKnXNgYJGxnCuiRGyakOwLUBZE7BWI2OTWIgrAA)

Find the last nonzero element in each prefix of the input array.

```
pZ‼l
p       For each prefix:
 Z‼     Remove zeros
   l    Last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 44 bytes

```
(F(L)(f x(_(_ L))(L((F(i)(?(L i)i($([ i))))x
```

This is an anonymous function taking one argument.

Explanation:

```
(F(L)               ; Anonymous function F(L)
  (f x (_ (_ L))    ; For x in range(len(L))
    (L              ; Implicit indexing
      (F(i)         ; Anonymous function F(i)
        (? (L i)    ; If L[i] is not 0:
          i         ; Return i; otherwise:
          ($ ([ i)) ; Recurse ($) with i decremented
        )           ; Then, we call this new function on x
      )             ; And use the return value as the index from line 3
      x             ; No final close-parens
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 21 bytes

The top half seems a bit wasteful, but I'm not sure what to do about it...

```
""?"
" #"
;  ;
,\!:
@
```

I/O via linefeed-delimited lists.

[Try it online.](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=IiI_IgoiICMiCjsgIDsKLFwhOgpA&input=MQowCjIKMAo3CjcKNwowCjUKMAowCjAKOQoxCjAKMAowCjAKMAotMQowCjUKMAowCi03CjIzCjAKMAotNDIKMAowCjAKMQoyCjMKNAotMTIzNA)

The idea is to keep the last printed thing on the stack and discard zeroes whenever we find them.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Büttner.

```
If[#2==0,##]&~FoldList~#&
```

Comment: `If[#2==0,##]&~FoldList~#&`?

Answer (score 2):

## C 45 Bytes

```
#define F(a,s) while(s--) *a=*a?*a++:*(a++-1)
```

### Here's my test program

Go easy as it's my first try at code golf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
#define F(a,s) while(s--) *a=*a?*a++:*(a++-1)

void printSolutions(int * solutions, int size)
{
  do {
    printf("%d ", *solutions++);
  } while (--size > 0);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  static int testCase1[] = {1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9};
  static int testCase2[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
  static int testCase3[] = {-1, 0, 5, 0, 0, -7};
  static int testCase4[] = {23, 0, 0, -42, 0, 0, 0};
  static int testCase5[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  static int testCase6[] = {-1234};
  int * p;
  int s;
  printSolutions(testCase1, ARRAYSIZE(testCase1));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase1);
  p = testCase1;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase1, ARRAYSIZE(testCase1));
  printSolutions(testCase2, ARRAYSIZE(testCase2));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase2);
  p = testCase2;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase2, ARRAYSIZE(testCase2));
  printSolutions(testCase3, ARRAYSIZE(testCase3));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase3);
  p = testCase3;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase3, ARRAYSIZE(testCase3));
  printSolutions(testCase4, ARRAYSIZE(testCase4));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase4);
  p = testCase4;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase4, ARRAYSIZE(testCase4));
  printSolutions(testCase5, ARRAYSIZE(testCase5));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase5);
  p = testCase5;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase5, ARRAYSIZE(testCase5));
  printSolutions(testCase6, ARRAYSIZE(testCase6));
  s = ARRAYSIZE(testCase6);
  p = testCase6;
  F(p, s);
  printSolutions(testCase6, ARRAYSIZE(testCase6));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running your test program on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/pG2jMu) doesn't seem to work - it just duplicates the first number.

Comment: That's strange.  I don't see where I'm relying on undefined behavior.  Maybe some compiler optimization gone wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure, either (I'm not super-well-versed in C). Both [CodingGrounds](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) and [codepad](http://codepad.org/hgMVdqIV) have the same behavior.

Comment: Also, welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Comment: Thanks, slow day in work and I usually just read through these...

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 36 bytes

```
[ 0 [ dup 0 = -rot ? ] accumulate* ]
```

(Only works locally in Factor 0.98 or later. TIO is missing `accumulate*`.) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

### Explanation

- `0` Push a zero to the data stack for `accumulate*` to use later. This is a 'starter' element so that a binary operation can be performed on something with the first element of the input sequence.
- `[ dup 0 = -rot ? ]` Push a quotation to the data stack for `accumulate*` to use later. This is a function that says *"Return the non-zero input if possible. Otherwise, return the second input."* Shorter but harder to read than `[ [ nip ] unless-zero ]`.
- `accumulate*` Like `reduce`, except the intermediate results are mapped into a sequence of the same size as the input sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
{y+x*~y}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpSu0KrrrI25n@agqGCgYIREJuDoYGCKRCDoCUXRA4KgTxdQ7i0rjmQb2QMYZsYwZUYAo0yVjABKzYyNvkPAA)

Take the cumulative sums of the input, resetting to 0 whenever a new non-zero value is encountered in the list.

If the 0's in the input are [replaced with nulls](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NKi7mf5qCoYKBn4IRiDAHQyDDFERAkCUXVAUSAgrpGiKr0zUHChkZw3gmRshKDYGGGyuYgDUZGZv8BwA) (`0N`), `^\` (fill-scan) suffices for two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>34</s> 25 bytes

```
f={it.collect{it?n=it:n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/zbY6s0QvOT8nJzW5BMi0z7PNLLHKq639X1CUmVeSk6eQphFtqKNgoKNgBCbNYQjINgWTEGQZq8mFoQWBUGV1DVH165qjyhsZw2VMjHCYYQh2EVChCbrZRsZAof8A)

A more readable solution:

```
f = { // define new closure
  it.collect { // taking advantage of implicit "it". collect applies the closure
               // on every element in order and returns the new, mapped array
    it ? // Groovy Boolean evaluation: 0 = false, 1+ = true
    n = it // assign value to holding variable (if not 0). assignments are expressions
    :
    n // in Groovy, if no return, last expression evaluated is returned
  } // same as above, returns the mapped array
} // end of closure
```

Groovy is supposed to be similar to Java (and it is), but the [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66035/107299) is more than two times longer. Just something to think about.

EDIT: reduced it by 9 bytes(!) by not declaring the `n` variable beforehand (saves 6 bytes), and using a ternary operator instead of an `if` (saves 3 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ɖ∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJluKIqCIsIiIsIlsxLDAsMiwwLDcsNyw3LDAsNSwwLDAsMCw5XSJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 14 bytes

```
+(\S+) 0/\1 \1
```

1 byte shorter than Retina!!

[Live demo and test cases.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%2B%28%5CS%2B%29%200%2F%5C1%20%5C1&input=1%200%202%200%207%207%207%200%205%200%200%200%209%0A1%200%200%200%200%200%0A-1%200%205%200%200%20-7%0A23%200%200%20-42%200%200%200%0A1%202%203%204%0A-1234)

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 12 bytes

```
0╗,`╜@;I;╗`M
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=30bb2c60bd403b493bbb604d&input=%5B1,%200,%202,%200,%207,%207,%207,%200,%205,%200,%200,%200,%209%5D)

Explanation:

```
0╗,    initialize first register to 0 and get input
`...`M map the function over the input:
  ╜@;I    push the result of (a if a else <value in register 0>)
  ;╗      dupe result and push to register 0
```

Comment: I was thinking this challenge had no seriously answer...and rather than check, I sat down and wrote this exact solution byte-for-byte.

Comment: @quintopia Hush, people are going to think you're my sock :P

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 21 characters

```
0=$p
<N>=@set{p;$0}$0
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '0=$p;<N>=@set{p;$0}$0' <<< '23 0 0 -42 0 0 0'
23 23 23 -42 -42 -42 -42
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 20 Bytes

```
a=>a.map(b=>c=b?b:c)
```

Explanation:

```
a=>           // Define anonymous function which takes argument a
  a.map(      // Loop through input
    b=>       // Looping function
      c=b     // Assign c to the loop value (returns b)
      ?b:c    // Ternary Operator: If b (previous expression) is truthy (Non-zero integers are) return b else return c (last value)          
)
```

Comment: `b||c` saves one byte over `b?b:c`.

Comment: Although then you just end up with @Dendrobium's answer.

Comment: His is surperior, I don't want to impersonate him

Comment: (I hadn't seen his answer when I wrote my first comment.)

Comment: You're fine, but if his is better, than is better so be it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 9 bytes

```perl
$;=$_||=$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/F2lYlvqbGVuX/f0MuAy4jIDYHQwMuUyAGQct/@QUlmfl5xf91C3IA)

### Explanation

This reads each number in as `$_` (`-p`), then sets `$;` to `$_`, after first setting `$_` to `$;` if `$_` is falsy (`0`) and is implicitly `print`ed (`-p`). Requires `-l` as otherwise `$_` would include `\n` [which would mean `0` isn't falsy](https://tio.run/##Dcg7CoAwEAXAqzwWYSNETGNj40UCYuEnEJKwiYWXd7WYZsoucVItElIzTGxRR59G/zvFggmh4t9uxQJucrfrYczgY4v14R5HFhhyZEHOJ@pV31xayKnqED8). The final `;` can be omitted as `-p` (well, specifically the `-n` part of `-p`) adds `while(<STDIN>){` ... `;}` around your code, resulting in `$;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 54 bytes

```
INPUT n
FOR i=1TO n
INPUT x
IF x=0THEN x=p
?x
p=x
NEXT
```

Input is the length of the list, followed by the numbers in the list one at a time. (Compare [this I/O default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/16766), which is the same basic idea even though it refers specifically to passing an array to a function.)

You can try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

#### Ungolfed

```
INPUT arrayLength
FOR i = 1 TO arrayLength
  INPUT number
  IF number = 0 THEN number = previous
  PRINT number
  previous = number
NEXT i
```

Comment: Is there somewhere I can test this? It has been too long since I've written any variant of Basic for me to remember any syntax, etc. I'm sure it is fine, but I always like to check for my own questions!

Comment: Sure--you can run it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack), though you have to type it in by hand.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch 147 bytes

```bat
@Set A=%* &@Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@Set "L=%A: ="&If .!C!==. Set "C=%"
@Set "A=%A: ="&2>nul Set/AL/L&&Set/AC=L&<nul Set/p=!C! &Set "L=%"
```

Approach:
Update Value to output only when value is non zero

How:

Line one: Arg asssignment and environment prep. Defines the array from arg to the batch file IE: `4 1 0 2 4 3`

Line two: Uses a substring operation for each whitespace present in the string with an if condition to isolate the first substring preceding a space for assignment to `L`ast and `C`Current variables.

Line three: Uses Substring modification to iterate through the array from each space in the substring; divides the `L`ast value by itself and on command success (`&&`) transfers the `L`ast value to `C`urrent. (a 0 value results in divide by zero error, redirected to nul). `C`urrent value is output after each step of the substitution.

---

Example Input / output:

```
4 3 2 0 3
4 3 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 37 bytes

```
Prompt A
For(I,2,dim(ʟA
ʟA(I)+ʟA(I-1)not(ʟA(I→ʟA(I
End
```

Output is stored in `ʟA`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 44 bytes

```python
g=lambda l,s=0:l and[a:=l[0]or s]+g(l[1:],a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBjsIgEIbP9SnmJmTRtLSmaxNOPkbDgd0qNkFoSvdgjM9eARdqyc9k@OdjmDDcp6vR5fcwzrNkStx@OgGKWJY3CoTuWtEw1ebcjGD5l0SqLRpOBJ4vzvkV9kzAGvU39UZDrwEQagsCOQEaYh3l8kOIbx05AQ8WAaQfYB3ApCPHZJNlWWy7aOmwKMG7Yv3krva4d/1O3Z0db9AysRVdPeIrcYfaKnzO5xzHVP@TxdMyEy2r9xg@wbjZgFvC2vM4gUT@NzEwlj6UwGV7ciY8fOkJXd@BNhMM7gog6bKHRBHGT7zfzi8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å»‚0Kθ
```

Unfortunately 05AB1E lacks a logical-OR builtin, and a bitwise-OR isn't what we want here.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuh3Y8aZhl4n9vx/3@0oY6CgY6CEZg0hyEg2xRMQpBlLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w62Hdj9qmGXgfW7H/1qd/9HRhjoGOkZAbA6GBjqmQAyClrE6CmBJKARxdQ3hCnTNQQJGxhCOiRFCkSHQOGMdE4h6I2OT2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Å»      # Cumulative left-reduce the (implicit) input-list by:
  ‚     #  Pair the current and previous integers together
   0K   #  Remove any potential 0
     θ  #  And pop and push the last item of this singleton-list/pair
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
êæαç┤o╘
```

Prints all values on a separated line to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wqsPLzm08vPzRlCX5j6bO@P/fUMdAxwiIzcHQQMcUiEHQkssQygJCLl1DuJSuOZeRMYRlYgSVNgQaYaxjAlRmZGwCAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ê       # Push the input as integer-array
 æ      # Foreach over these integers, using four characters as inner code-block:
  α     #  Wrap the top two values on the stack into a list
        #  (the first iteration will pair with an implicit 0)
   ç    #  Remove all 0s (falsey filter)
    ┤   #  Push it's last item to the stack (unfortunately doesn't pop the list)
     o  #  Print it with trailing newline (without popping)
 ╘      # After the foreach: empty the stack (otherwise it would implicitly output the
        # entire stack; feel free to remove it in the TIO-link to see the difference)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 19 bytes

```
&nry[p[s!]plu9`oy]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tr6gyuiC6WDG2IKfUMiG/Mrbg/38jYy4DINQ1MQLTBgA)

This works by running through all the numbers on the list and remember the current number if it's non-zero.  Then it unconditionally deleted the current character and what's printed is whatever number is in the backup cell.

```
&nr                  - read all the nunbers into the stack, reverse them
   y[p          y]   - loop while the stack length is >0
      [  ]           - if/then, true is current number !=0
       s             - save the number to the backup cell
        !            - flip to 0 to exit the loop
                  p  - delete loop boolean so it doesn't print
          p          - delete current number
           lu        - load backup cell and print
             9`o     - print a LF
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 49 bytes

```
#(reduce(fn[c i](conj c(if(= i 0)(last c)i)))[]%)
```

Well this is very boring. [TIO](https://tio.run/##NcbBCoMwEEXRvV/xoAhvwIUVSumiXxKyKGMGRkIsqX5/LJbC5XA1r8teU2uck8FwYU3zrolWgsIjdS0LlG58wjEK8@uzQcVFJMRepOv4rl62XEBDuA4YB0yn93/fv53@ekSR1g4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 80 bytes

```
L=l[1...i-1]
A=L[LL>0]
f(l)=[\{l[i]=0:A[A.\length],l[i]\}\for i=[1...l.\length]]
```

Most likely golfable, though I don't see anything at the moment.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hsv5crawey)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ljtalysfa2)