# Replace by most recent nonzero

Tags: code-golf, string, number, array

Given a non-empty list of decimal digits (`0`, `1`, ..., `9`), replace each zero by the most recent nonzero, if possible.

**Example 1**: given

```
1 4 3 0 0 7 5 5 0 3
```

the output should be

```
1 4 3 3 3 7 5 5 5 3
```

Note how the first two zeros are replaced by `3`, which is the most recent (i.e. rightmost) nonzero. Similarly, the last zero is replaced by `5`.

**Example 2**: given

```
0 0 4 0 0 5 0
```

the output should be

```
0 0 4 4 4 5 5
```

Note how it is not possible to replace the first two zeros, because there isn't a nonzero number to the left ot them.

#### Additional rules

- Input can be taken by [any reasonable means](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Format is flexible as usual. In particular, it can be a list of numbers, an array, a string representation of an array, a string of digit characters ...
- [Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

Input, then output

```
1 4 3 0 0 7 5 5 0 3
1 4 3 3 3 7 5 5 5 3

0 0 4 0 0 5 0
0 0 4 4 4 5 5

0 0 0
0 0 0

0
0

0 1
0 1

4 2 1 0
4 2 1 1

8 0 0 0 6
8 8 8 8 6
```

Comment: [Dupe?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65770/31625) I think this challenge is generally worded better but I'm not sure being single positive digits and leading zeros changes the result in enough languages.

Comment: @Fry I’m not sure. I didn’t remember yours. But the leading zeros do make a difference. What do others think?

Comment: Three votes for a dupe from Code-Gold members is enough for me.

Comment: @Adm I changed my mind (and edited my comment) because of the leading zeros. But I’m not sure that makes it different enough. You are probably right

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Your challenge is based on a SO question and the accepted answer there is mine :-) I really should have remembered!

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah! But I figured nearly 4 years was long enough that I could forgive you ;)

Comment: I was actually going to post this challenge, but I figured "eh, someone's probably already done it" - turns out I also posted an answer on that 4 years ago :P

Comment: @Doorknob Heh, your memory is as bad as mine is

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>22</s>  21 bytes

```javascript
A=>A.map(x=>A=x||~~A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BDoIwEEX3nqLLkozQ2oJsasI5jIsGwWiQEjGGBeHqdUpjIpT5m0n@e5P2oT@6L1/37r1vzbWytbKFOhXxU3d0wEUN4zhNRWRL0/amqeLG3GhNzxwkCGCYI6QYBuISRSRJiG9cfJOC2K1kp8lZRtFpflD2jQuKW9ofTpYaC/AQ/eHhZb4Fz5f5GpZwAB4@BGHfBEI@f5VBtlRQyMEns18)

#### Commented

```javascript
A =>          // A[] = input array
  A.map(x =>  // for each value x in A[]:
    A =       //   update A to:
      x ||    //     either x, if it's not equal to 0
      ~~A     //     or A coerced to an integer otherwise
  )           // end of map()
```

Because we're re-using the input array \$A[\:]\$ to store the last non-zero value, two special cases arise if the 2nd part of the condition is executed on the 1st iteration:

- if \$A[\:]\$ is a singleton array containing \$0\$, `~~A` is equal to `~~0`
- if \$A[\:]\$ is an array of several elements (starting with \$0\$), `~~A` is equal to `~~NaN`

which gives the expected \$0\$ in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
f@x_:=f@0=x;Map@f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n65g@z/NoSLeyjbNwcC2wto3scAhDSSqEFCUmVfioKUBFtHk4krXd6jmqjbUUTDRUTDWUTAAI3MdBVMwArKNa3W4qiHCJjB5kAxCGMKE8g1BNFChEZAJlbKAaQMis1qu2v8A)

Inspired by [kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206836/12025) to a question on Mathematica Stack Exchange, which I assume was the inspiration for this challenge. :)

In the body of `f`, the value of `f[0]` is redefined to be the input, which is also returned. That way, whenever `f` is called with `0` after the first time it's called, it will always yield the "remembered" result, which is updated when `f` is called again with a nonzero argument.

Thanks to [@attinat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/attinat) for 2 bytes.

[mikado's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206927/12025) yields a 20 byte solution:

```
FoldList[#2/. 0->#&]
```

Comment: simple [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n65g@983scAhjSvNoSLeyjbNwcC24n9AUWZeiYNWur5DNVe1oY6CiY6CsY6CARiZ6yiYghGQbVyrw1UNETaByYNkEMIQJpRvCKKBCo2ATKiUBUwbEJnVctX@BwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") with `@` instead of `[ ]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
s/([^0])0/$1$1/&&redo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXyM6ziBW00BfxVDFUF9NrSg1Jf//fwMDEwMDU4N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: [Here's another 21](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YMTrOINZAW9GgRklFzUBJ31IxPfX/f0MTYwMDc1NTA2MuAwMTAwNTg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA), using math.

Comment: @Grimy Interesting idea, but it doesn't seem to work if the preceding digit is a nine: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YMTrOINZAW9GgRklFzUBJ31IxPfX/f0MTYwMDc1NTA2MuAwNLAwNTg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Right, my bad. It takes at least 2 bytes to fix it, so it's not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ȯ@\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EeoeY////G@goGOoomOgoGOsoGICRuY6CKRgB2cYA)

-2 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggMan (it's close to being an entirely new solution because 5 -> 3 bytes is a 40% deduction and that's like half the code lol)

## Explanation

```
ȯ@\  Main Program
  \  Cumulative Reduce
ȯ@   Logical OR (inverted; basically "right OR left")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 11 bytes

```
{$[y;y;x]}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFET3/YpZuNCFkJi0luZTaqBuIlKpULpIkfrr8T4ss8mcOeGO5@kxlZK6z6Ffwxpy3G5lkfadu4QchvcYjkO6P18hkzCf4lYtvYWHg6FcUVMMXAUo5Sit4SLJrHmRSSRNO4eUXdgHI4CLLla45eJxoRO86Utgq7/QEG7/aWL5AQ)

`{` `}\` scan - starting with the first element, apply the function in `{` `}` between the current result and the next element. collect intermediate results in a list.

`$[y;y;x]` cond - if the right argument `y` is truthy (not 0), return it, otherwise return the left argument `x`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ηε0†θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/k9v/c9nNbDR41LDi343@tzn9DE2MDA3NTUwNjLgMDExMTU1MA)

For each prefix of the input, filter 0s to the front, then get its last digit. Yes, filter-to-the-front is somehow a single-byte built-in (`†`). I didn't think I'd ever need it, but here we are.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 65 bytes

```
s->{while(!s.equals(s=s.replaceAll("(.) 0","$1 $1")));return s;};
```

A Function that repeatedly replaces "N 0" with "N N" until such time as the String stops changing, then returns it.