# The Cantor Function

Tags: code-golf, math, fractal

The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is continuous everywhere and constant [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), but has an average slope of 1:

[image: fncantor]

The function can be found recursively:

\$f_0(x)=x\$

\$f_{n+1}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}f_n(3x)&x\in[0,\frac{1}{3})\\ \frac{1}{2}&x\in[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})\\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}f_n(3x-2)&x\in[\frac{2}{3},1] \end{matrix}\right.\$

The Cantor function is the limit of this process, \$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\$:

[image: iteration limit]

## The Challenge

Given real x (which can assume the form of a float or rational number) of the interval \$[0,1]\$ and nonnegative integer n, return \$f_n(x)\$.

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Assume only valid input will be given.
- Error should be under one ten-thousandth (±0.0001) for the test cases.

## Test Cases

```
In: 0.3 3
Out: 0.3875

In: 0.1 0
Out: 0.1

In: 0.29 4
Out: 0.375

In: 0.11 5
Out: 0.2415625
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/46821/36398) (draw \$f_n\$ in ASCII art)

Comment: The average slope is actually 0.

Comment: Using the average slope formula m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and the points (0,0) and (1,1) one can see the average slope is 1 @PyRulez

Comment: In any case, the slope is 0 almost everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>25</s> 27 bytes

```apl
{⊥1⊥1⌊⊤1∘≠⍛×\0,3⊤⍵×3*⍺}÷2*⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR11JDMO7petS1xPBRx4xHnQse9c4@PD3GQMcYKPSod@vh6cZaj3p31R7ebqT1qGvx/7RHbRMe9fY96mo@tN74UdvER31Tg4OcgWSIh2fwf2OFNAUDPWMuAzBtyGUCpo0suUwhAoZcEBXmRlApYyMuXV1dLg0jBaNHvVsMFAw1H3UuNFAwVQA6Rg@oQMGQi0vT382NyzPPCqRcwVhBwb@0BMy2MDeFChsCFcKEDaFiRpYKJnClCJWGQLOhokYmhqZmRqYA)

Inline tacit function, which can be used as `n f x`.

Uses the method described in [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207417/78410). I changed one part of the algorithm:

- This one doesn't consider integer and fractional parts separately; rather, the fractional part is included in the last digit. (e.g. the base-3 representation of 8.1 is `[2, 2.1]`.) Later, at the step where 2s are changed into 1s, all digits `≥2` are reduced by 1 instead, and **(+2 bytes)** the fractional part of the last digit is removed if its integer part is 1.

```apl
{⊥1⊥1⌊⊤1∘≠⍛×\0,3⊤⍵×3*⍺}÷2*⊣  ⍝ Left: n, Right: x
{                ⍵×3*⍺}  ⍝ 3^n*x
               3⊤        ⍝ Convert to base 3; last digit may have fractional part
             0,  ⍝ Prepend 0 to avoid error on ⊤ over an empty array
       1∘≠⍛×\    ⍝ Keep each digit unless at least one 1 appears somewhere on its left
      ⊤  ⍝ Convert each digit to binary
    1⌊   ⍝ Clamp all digits >1 to 1 (effectively cuts the fractional part of
         ⍝ the last digit if its integer part is 1)
  1⊥     ⍝ Treat the binary of each digit as base 1 and convert back to a number
         ⍝ Since all numbers are <3, effectively "decrement if ≥2"
 ⊥  ⍝ Treat as base 2 and convert to single number
÷2*⊣  ⍝ Divide by 2^n
```

Comment: @LuisMendo He doesn't; I was just checking that myself, in case it helped me golf more bytes from my answer. (To be specific, `3 f 0.72` is returning `0.68` instead of the correct `0.625` that your answer gives.)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah, so ``1∘≠⍛×\`` works for the first `n-1` base 3 digits; it's only the case of when the `nth` digit is a `1` that his answer doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I think I have a +2 bytes fix; I'll update the post when I get to my PC.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 33 bytes

```
3y^i*1&\3_YAt1=f"O@QJh(wkw]XB+wW/
```

Inputs are `n`,  then `x`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/37gyLlPLUC3GOD7SscTQNk3J3yHQK0OjPLs8NsJJuzxcH6iEy0DPGAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N@4Mi5Ty1Atxjg@0rHE0DZNyd8h0CtDozy7PDbCSbs8XP@/S8h/Yy4DPSAGkoZcJkDSyJLLFMQxBAA).

### Approach

The code uses a non-recursive approach, based on the procedure for computing the Cantor function \$f_\infty(x)\$ that appears in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Definition), modified so that it computes \$f_n(x)\$ instead:

1. Multiply \$x\$ by \$3^n\$.
2. Decompose the result into integer part \$M\$ and decimal part \$F\$.
3. Express \$M\$ in base \$3\$. Let \$B\$ be the resulting sequence of up to \$n\$ digits from the set \$\{0, 1, 2\}\$.
4. If \$B\$ contains a \$1\$, replace every digit after the first \$1\$ by \$0\$.
5. Replace any remaining \$2\$s with \$1\$s.
6. Interpret the result as a binary number.
7. If \$B\$ didn't contain \$1\$s, add \$F\$.
8. Divide by \$2^n\$.

### Some golfing tricks

- Using a `for` loop instead of an `if` branch for step 4 saved quite a few bytes. The value for the branch condition (index of first \$1\$) needed to be used within the branch code (to replace subsequent digits by \$0\$). This is cumbersome in MATL, as the `if` branch consumes (pops) its condition. Instead, the loop solves this more elegantly: since the branch condition was either empty or a vector of indices of \$1\$s in \$B\$, it can be looped over: if it's empty the loop is simply not entered. And then the loop variable can be used within the loop code. The fact that the loop, unlike the conditional branch, may iterate *several* times (if there are more than one \$1\$ digit) is not harmful here, because the substitutions in step 4 are idempotent: they simply overwrite some of the previous \$0\$s with new \$0\$s.
- Step 7 is partly handled within the `for` loop. Specifically, if the loop is entered, the decimal part \$F\$ should not be added later on. To implement this, the loop iteration replaces \$F\$ (previously stored in the stack) by \$0\$. This is done by a round-down operation (`k`), which is convenient because it uses only 1 byte and is, again, idempotent: the result remains equal to \$0\$ in all iterations after the first.
- The MATL function that converts from binary to decimal (`XB`) treats any digit other than \$0\$ as if it were \$1\$, which is useful for steps 5 and 6.

### Commented code

```
3         % Step 1. Push 3
y         % Implicit input: n. Duplicate from below: pushes n below and
          % above the 3
^         % Power: gives 3^n
i*        % Input: x. Multiply: gives x*3^n
1         % Step 2. Push 1
&\        % Two-output modulus: gives modulus (F) and quotient (M)
3_YA      % Step 3. Convert to base 3, with digis 0, 1, 2
t1=       % Step 4 and part of step 7. Duplicate. Compare each entry with 1
f         % Vector (possibly empty) of indices of true values; that is,
          % positions of digit 1
"         % For each index k
  O       %   Push 0
  @Q      %   Push k+1
  Jh(     %   Write 0 at positions k+1, k+2, ..., end
  wkw     %   Swap, round down, swap. This replaces F by 0
]         % End
XB        % Steps 5 and 6. Convert from binary to decimal, with digit 2
          % interpreted as 1
+         % Part of step 7. Add F, or 0
wW/       % Step 8. Swap (brings n to top), 2 raised to that, divide
          % Implicit display
```

Comment: So, much like my second approach, but without the bug... I'd better go back and fix my answer.

Comment: @Neil Nah. Your current 34 byte count is perfect :-P

Comment: Sadly it didn't work for `x=1`. (In a deleted comment, @Bubbler pointed out that @fireflame241 had the same problem with his answer.)

Comment: (But the good news is that I can use @Bubbler's adjustment to your method, and this actually saves me 2 bytes overall, which is almost back down to the original byte count.)

Comment: Yeah, pity that MATL's base conversion cannot handle non-integer values

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 38 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

```apl
{×⍺×1-⍵:2÷⍨(1∘≤+(1≠⌊)×(⍺-1)∇⊢-⌊)3×⍵⋄⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/rw9Ee9uw5PN9R91LvVyujw9ke9KzQMH3XMeNS5RBvI6FzwqKdL8/B0DaAqXUPNRx3tj7oW6YLEjEE6tz7qbgGStf/THrVNeNTb96ir@VHvmke9Ww6tN37UNvFR39TgIGcgGeLhGfzfB6xmlbGCgYKJgimQBGOuIIiwgR5QQs8QiI0sQQwgCwgNFQy5fHSCdDR8FNIOrQjSBAA)

Combines the cases of the recurrence using

$$
f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{cases}
0+1×f_n(3x-0), x\in[0,1/3) \\
1+0×f_n(3x-1), x\in[1/3,2/3)\\
1+1×f_n(3x-2), x\in[2/3,1]
\end{cases}
$$

which can be condensed (note \$u=3x\$) to

$$
f_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{3}u\right) = \frac{1}{2}\big(
(u<1)+(\lfloor u\rfloor\neq 1)×f_n(u-\lfloor u \rfloor)\big)
$$ (since comparisons resolve to True=1 or False=0). This fails for `x=1` since then `⌊u` is 3 instead of 2. Using ceiling instead of floor would then fail for `x=0`, so it ends up shorter to check specifically for `x=1`.

```apl
{ ... } ⍺=n; ⍵=x
×⍺×1-⍵: ⍝ If n>0 or x≠1:
 3×⍵      ⍝ Let u=3x
  (⍺-1)∇⊢-⌊ ⍝ f(n-1, u-floor(u)) (`1∘|` ←→ `⊢-⌊`)
  (1≠⌊)×    ⍝ Multiply by 1 unless floor(u)=1
  1∘≤+      ⍝ Add 1 unless 1 > u
 2÷⍨      ⍝ Half of this
⋄       ⍝ Else:
 ⍵        ⍝ x
```

Comment: @Bubbler Fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't `u < 1` in your explanation be `u ≥ 1`?

Comment: `If n>0 or x≠1` - you mean `and`? you can avoid `x≠1` by replacing `⊢-⌊` with `2|⊢`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x:n and(1<x*3<2or x//.5+f(n-1,3*x%1))/2or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoNADADvfUUuhY1NXWP0UNHHrMiiYKOIh/T1q7a9DMMcZv3s46KSUuzm8O6HAErWKAQdHLeWSVsuG5j3ef2ITp9MktmdEf23p3iRQGFScEUuJEiXMBU/KV9U/RNTjc0NYN0m3d15I0NMBw)

Python 3 is used just for the `/2` to do float division; Python 2 would be a byte longer with `/2.`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 69 bytes

of course mathematica has a built-in for this: `CantorStaircase[x]` but you cannot choose `n`

```
x_~f~0:=x
x_~f~n_:=If[(y=3x)<1,f[y,n-1]/2,If[y<2,.5,.5+f[y-2,n-1]/2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/78ivi6tzsDKtoILzMqLt7L1TIvWqLQ1rtC0MdRJi67UydM1jNU30gEKV9oY6eiZApE2kK1rBJWJjf0fUJSZV6LgkBZtoGeso2Acy4UkYKijYIAiYGSpo2CCqgSoxjT2/38A)

*@JonathanAllan saved 2 bytes*

Here is also another approach from @att which is great!

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes

```
If[#2<1,#,If[1<3#<2,1,(s=Boole[2#>1])+#0[3#-2s,#2-1]]/2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtWtnIxlBHWQfIMrQxVrYx0jHU0Si2dcrPz0mNNlK2M4zV1FY2iDZW1jUq1lE20jWMjdU3ilX7H1CUmVei4JAWbaBnrKNgHMuFJGCoo2CAImBkqaNggqoEqMY09v9/AA)

Comment: Using a condition of `x<2/3` and swapping the branches would save a byte. Can you place `3x` in a variable, say `y`, in five bytes (or less)? If so you can save a byte (or more) by then replacing `1/3` with `1`, `2/3` with `2` and the two occurrences of `3x` with `y`.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtWtnIxlBHWQfIMrQxVrYx0jHU0Si2dcrPz0mNNlK2M4zV1FY2iDZW1jUq1lE20jWMjdU3ilX7H1CUmVei4JAWbaBnrKNgHMuFJGCoo2CAImBkqaNggqoEqMY09v9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x:n and[f(n-1,e:=3*x),1+e//2*f(n-1,e-2)][e>1]/2or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEADvvmKP2bo13URBA/UjpYdIEyzoNoQe4uujxV6GYQ6TPutzEXtNudbYv/z7MXkQKk7AyzREJS1TcL1tChIfg9am2WNrcBzCnUdtlgylxo0EArOA6k6WLNImTN1fzI3Oe2K6oDsApDzLqn5DKoj1Cw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
_2çH+.
ñH¥.ç<2$?<1$?
×3çɗ⁸⁹?’}
```

A full program accepting \$x\$ and \$n\$ which prints a floating-point representation of \$f_n(x)\$

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//XzLDp0grLgrDsUjCpS7DpzwyJD88MSQ/CsOXM8OnyZfigbjigbk/4oCZff///y4yOf80)**

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Expects `(n)(x)`.

```javascript
n=>g=x=>n--?((x*=3)<1?g(x):x<2||1+g(x-2))/2:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcw9DoJAEEDh3pPMaHbdHykkDHTeg8CywZAdI8RMwd1XsaOhe8WX92w/7dy9x9eiEvchD5QT1ZGE6qRUAyBn8ljZJoJgKZVbV3v5tXKIV1dK7jjNPAU9cYQBPILR3qBe@DFK6KFAPO2J2Yg9JLeNuPsRKf4XuyP5Cw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                   // outer function taking n
  g = x =>             // inner recursive function taking x
    n-- ?              // decrement n; if it was not equal to 0:
      (                //   compute f_n(x):
        (x *= 3) < 1 ? //     multiply x by 3; if the result is less than 1:
          g(x)         //       use g(x)
        :              //     else:
          x < 2 ||     //       use 1 if x is less than 2
          1 + g(x - 2) //       otherwise, use 1 + g(x - 2)
      ) / 2            //   in all cases, divide the result by 2
    :                  // else:
      x                //   stop recursion and return f_0(x) = x
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>73</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>69</s></sup> 68 bytes

```c
float f(n,x)float x;{x*=3;x=n--?(x<1?f(n,x):x<2?:1+f(n,x-2))/2:x/3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHtaoMwFIb/9yoOgpC0SWu0bmuj64@xq1jLEI2b0MWiMsKK1@7yYW33IRhOcp73PSc5OX3L82Eoj3XWQYkkUdjFip/VPI24SiWlO6QStnPprUrC3ZYt7I6GGK/CrVpFvB8q2cFHVkn0WVcFnp1noL/8PWvm0LwcIIWzt1fP4V5tnvQfewRu95HXc6tw9TvRdq/KyYJlRCBYMrOEGxuyETY1LSodakACawLxDzehTkJ1orCQNXy4jyfPyMXhmsV34SSsG0DGvpKFUFoW8DFMoK2@RF2iiytejQcaxxwWC8thcC9w7cK4jPeyxIFPgCkkL2n5J@30rQbcEH5nhM5Md/xfXIhjl2msBQripnAJyKUSCPBIzVOg7MqcGt1eiTzToF8Qew@/BPpoVr/dSz1KqY8JtESPerTTL7YMgoAdxm77WT98Aw)

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!*
*Save a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Comment: I was just about to suggest [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHtaoMwFIb/9yoOgpC0sTWxbqva@mPsKmYZonETulhURljx2l0@rN2XYDzJ@5w353gK77UoxrE6NXkPFRJEYhvL@CKX@yCWe@F5KZIJTa0cyYSlNKIrs/UYxhsWyU0QD2MtenjPa4E@mrrEi8sC1FO85e0S2ucj7OHiZPKJZXL3qN7QIfB9HzhDbDJsAT3v@hdp0/x1QMBfU72wnQnpBOs7DSosqkECWwLhDzcuz1z2vDSQMXy4D2fPwMZsS8M7Nic2LSBtX4uSS5Xmx1OYQFd/8qZCV1e8mQ4UjmNYrQyHwf6BWxXaZerLEMd4BvRF4iqLP7LN7xRgp/Bb4UqZe/w/ueSnPldYBx7wm3g9tt@DahPSaROBZ4IbfG5VnRVydKVuSUxDbgXeQa/IrTC4XSbUYIXSCHQEOFGzt3aJ8l77vk@PU/nDYhi/AA) before your edit.

Comment: That's a much better direction to golf in. Was just think how on earth do I factor out the `/2` and the `x<2`, and there you have it: call recursively from two places. Since your golf is based on the original gave you -4 bytes - thanks! :D

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 70 <s>74</s> bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @FryAmTheEggman*

```python
f=lambda n,x:n and((1<=(t:=x*3))+f(n-1,t-2*(t>=2))*(t>=2or 1>t))/2or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDoIwEEXXcIpZzuCgtNVEieUixkUNaSTBoSFd4OkrRd389/IWP7zjcxJzDnNK3o7u9egdCC@tgJMeUV0txtYulSHaeZRacax1hbGzmujLaQbVRaJDtiX5vAwCg8CtLLDZGwZDvKliaH6qLwzHf177afV7WxZhHiSicD7xG4nSBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>76</s> ... <s>60</s> 58 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Robin Ryder, +1 byte to fix bug spotted by Neil, -2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
f=function(x,n,y=x*3)`if`(n,(min(f(y%%2,n-1),1)+!y<2)/2,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczbDoIwDIDhe55ihpBsWg7tmKfIu0BwUy4sCWACT49GDupd@@Vvm7EsuKubbHSZe3LZVTXLHhiGrN9qlVculwzyUbF0cggCAg5RAardZriQigl6Nb@QSaRBK@GL93A8GG9lhGRi/BqdIJ3bvxTBTEwpmj0ZzxcFX0V3t8JebzYsi9a25/UA6FMvO8Z6lsiIBekH13AS9MYX)

Un-golfed:

```r
cantor=f=function(x,n){
    y=3*x                               # define y=3*x
                                        # to save characters later.
    if(n==0){ x }                       # if n==0 just return x
    else {                              # otherwise
        (
         min(                           # whichever is smaller of:
            cantor(y%%2,n-1),           # - call self using y mod 2
                                        #   (this works for the first & last thirds
                                        #   but gives a result >1 for middle third)
            1)                          # - 1 (to fix the middle third)
         +(y>=2)                        # for the top third we need to add 1 to 
                                        # the result of the self call
        )
        /2                              # finally, we divide all above results by 2
    } 
}
```

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##VczdCoMwDAXge59C2E3Sxc2kdj@w7lkcQsGbCKLQPn1XpmwMcnHOxyFzHl66TLPPwYdVh2WcFCIpJW9NxH4MPSgBHyE9BU2A1Ahpw1jgwWigyKeXw7NQxP0htCdLFutDXcLt6qovM7Ub88/kTt2@/ZsyuY2lY3cRV@U3 "R – Try It Online") by avoiding some `if`s.

Comment: Thanks!  I managed to removed some more bytes in the meantime!

Comment: ...but combining this with your approach managed to shave-off another 2!  Thanks again!

Comment: `floor(y)` can be `y%/%1` for -3 bytes.

Comment: Super!  Thanks again!

Comment: [1 more byte](https://tio.run/##VczLCoMwEIXhvU@hlMCMnVZnYnpZpM9iEQJuRhCF5OlTQWnp7ufjcOY8vHWZZp@DD6sOyzgpRFJK3tYR@zH0oASQXoznAMkYIb0w1lWVTGN4y0Yo4nED7dWSxfJUbvG4u@LLTO3O/DN5Unds/6ZMbmfp2N3EFfkD "R – Try It Online") shaved off because operator precedence breaks your way. I think I'm out now!

Comment: I'd worry about `y=1` except that it can't happen with floating-point numbers since they can't represent `1/3` exactly...

Comment: @Neil - Thanks for spotting that.  It was a problem: somehow the non-exact representations seem to cancel-out if we specify ```1/3``` as x.  Fixed now, I think (at cost of +1 byte [```>1``` changed to ```>=1```])

Comment: Ah, I guess floating-point rounding could trip over this. Glad I could help!

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##VczbDoIwDIDhe55ihpBsWg7tmKfIu0BwUy4sCWACT49GDupd@@Vvm7EsuKubbHSZe3LZVTXLHhiGrN9qlVculwzyUbF0cggCAg5RAardZriQigl6Nb@QSaRBK@GL93A8GG9lhGRi/BqdIJ3bvxTBTEwpmj0ZzxcFX0V3t8JebzYsi9a25/UA6FMvO8Z6lsiIBekH13AS9MYX).

Comment: Thanks for the golfing wizardry, again, Giuseppe!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 78 bytes

```perl
sub f{my$b=pop;my$a=pop;$b--?($a<1/3?f(3*$a,$b):$a<2/3?1:1+f(3*$a-2,$b))/2:$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrTq3UiXJtiC/wBrISAQzVJJ0de01VBJtDPWN7dM0jLVUEnVUkjStgCJGQBFDK0NtiKiuEUhcU98IKFX7XyXeNs3B7b@BnrGCMZeBnqGCAZA0slQwAXEMFUz/5ReUZObnFf/XLUjMAQA)

Comment: Nice again! You can save a few bytes using `my($a,$b)=@_;` instead of the `pop`s though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔↨×ＮＸ³θ³ηＩ∕↨²Ｅη∧¬№…ηκ¹§⟦ι¹⊖ι⟧ιＸ²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xD4IwEIV3f0XHu6QagTg5ISwMEgY341DhIo3QQltQf32tmBiHl9zL@@7l1a0wtRad94UaJldO/ZUMjLhfpdbKm4KDsAQn2ZOFfwI5q/QjHAlnIwaXBLXhrTJSOciEdZDLWTb0bYg5O4oBWs5S1UCpA6KnD/iqO8pavUT30BEFpa5QDT3hLIPnLKfaUE/KUQMSL5xJRPwNiJcBiHvvd2y7iSK/nrs3) Link is to verbose version of code. Based on the Wikipedia entry, I convert the `3ⁿx` to base 3, then massage the digits so that the result can be interpreted as base 2 and divided by `2ⁿ`. Takes input in the order `n`, `x`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔↨×ＮＸ³θ³ηＩ∕
```

Multiply `x` by `3ⁿ` and convert it to base 3. The last entry includes any remaining fractional part.

```
Ｅη∧¬№…ηκ¹§⟦ι¹⊖ι⟧ι
```

Map over the digits. If there was a previous `1` then set this digit to zero, otherwise map the digit to itself, `1`, or subtract `1`, depending on the floor of the digit. This ensures that the last digit (with the remaining fractional part) is converted correctly.

```
Ｉ∕↨²...Ｘ²θ
```

Convert from base 2, divide by `2ⁿ`, and output the final decimal as a string.

Previous 34-byte solution did not work for `x=1`, as it only considered the decimal part of `x`:

```
Ｎθ≔×ＮＸ³θη≔⁻η⌊ηζＦθ≔⊘§⟦ζ¹⊕ζ⟧∕ηＸ³ιζＩζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xDoIwEIZ3n6LjNalGYpyYiMbIgCHGzThUqPQSaKEtaHj5WoNGtrvvvy/3F5KbQvPa@1S1vTv1zV0Y6Gi8SKzFSsEFG2FhHlJGcv0Mw4aRjoZN/q8PtdYGZIBjgBlvJ37GSjrIUPU2JJPx0IaER@RrHnk9iBISl6pSvOAqGYkYSVVhRCOUC5Gktw9wexywFDDOaiClvyK5QeVgx60LAo2935L1Kor8cqjf) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `n`, `x`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔×ＮＸ³θη
```

Multiply `x` by `3ⁿ`.

```
≔⁻η⌊ηζ
```

Take the decimal part of that.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop `n` times.

```
≔⊘§⟦ζ¹⊕ζ⟧∕ηＸ³ιζ
```

Depending on the next base 3 digit of the above product, replace the decimal part with half of itself, half of 1, or half of the sum.

```
Ｉζ
```

Output the final decimal as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3Im*1‰`s3в¹£εTYèsi1V]2βY≠i+}¹o/
```

Takes the loose inputs in the order \$n,x\$.

Port of [*@LuisMendo*'s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207417/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9vc2FiaWX//zNJbSox4oCwYHMz0LLCucKjzrVUWcOoc2kxVl0yzrJZ4omgaSt9wrlvL///NAowLjI5) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H/jiFwtw0cNGxKKjS9siji0@NzWkMjDK4ozDcNqa43ObYp81LkgU7s2Il//v45R2P/oaAM9Yx3jWB0gbahjAKaNLHVMIAKGOqaxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
3Im              # Push 3 to the power of the first input-integer
   *             # Multiply it by the (implicit) input-decimal
    1‰           # Get the divmod-1 to split the integer and decimal parts
      `s         # Pop and push them separated to the stack in reversed order
3в               # Convert the integer part to base-3 as list
  ¹£             # Only leave the first input-integer amount of base-3 digits
    ε            # Map this list to:
     T           #  Push 10
      Yè         #  Index `Y` into this
                 #  (`Y` is 2 by default, which wraps modulair indices into the 1)
     si          #  If the current digit we're mapping over is 1:
       1V        #   Set `Y` to 1
    ]            # Close both the if-statement and map
     2β          # Convert the resulting list from base-2 to an integer
       Y≠i }     # If `Y` is NOT 1:
          +      #  Add the decimal part that's still on the stack
            ¹o/  # And divide this by 2 to the power the first input-integer
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: If I put in `3 0.72` then I get `0.875` which seems wrong; I think it should be `0.625`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 71 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN93TNCp08jRtqyttjbUqrDPTNPJsbQ10KnSArEobQx0gqZOna6ipbwQRMdLRMwUibSBb1wgqo6mpWQs1zrOgKDOvRCNNw0DPWEfBWFPTmgshYqijYIAqYmSpo2CCpgioyhQoBDEQ5k4A)

```
f(x,n)={y=3*x;if(n==0,x,if(y<1,f(y,n-1)/2,if(y<2,.5,.5+f(y-2,n-1)/2)))}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN4-maVToKORpKtgqVHMpKORWalQCmcZaFZrWQG5mmkaegq2tgoGOQoUOkA8WqVSwUTDUUQAygBp1DTX1jSBScEkjHQU9UxBW0Aap0jWCqdMEqwORQNNrubgKijLzSjTSNAz0jHUUjDWBgggRoA0GqCJGljoKJmiKgKpMgUIQz0D9BPMbAA)

```
f(x, n) = {
  my(y = 3*x);
  if(n == 0, x,
    if(y < 1, f(y, n-1)/2,
      if(y < 2, .5, .5 + f(y-2, n-1)/2)
    )
  );
}

print(f(0.3, 3));
print(f(0.1, 0));
print(f(0.29, 4));
print(f(0.11, 5));
```